# Should I check in folder "node_modules" to Git when creating a Node.js app on Heroku?

Tags: git, node.js, heroku, npm, gitignore

I followed the basic *getting started* instructions for Node.js on Heroku here:

https://devcenter.heroku.com/categories/nodejs

These instructions don't tell you to create a .gitignore node_modules, and therefore imply that folder *node_modules* should be checked into Git.  When I included *node_modules* in the Git repository, my getting started application ran correctly.

When I followed the more advanced example at:

- *[Building a Real-time, Polyglot Application with Node.js, Ruby, MongoDB and Socket.IO](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/realtime-polyglot-app-node-ruby-mongodb-socketio)*
- https://github.com/mongolab/tractorpush-server  (source)

It instructed me to add folder *node_modules* to file *.gitignore*. So I removed folder *node_modules* from Git, added it to file *.gitignore*, and then redeployed. This time the deployment failed like so:

```
-----> Heroku receiving push
-----> Node.js app detected
-----> Resolving engine versions
       Using Node.js version: 0.8.2
       Using npm version: 1.0.106
-----> Fetching Node.js binaries
-----> Vendoring node into slug
-----> Installing dependencies with npm
       Error: npm doesn't work with node v0.8.2
       Required: node@0.4 || 0.5 || 0.6
           at /tmp/node-npm-5iGk/bin/npm-cli.js:57:23
           at Object.<anonymous> (/tmp/node-npm-5iGk/bin/npm-cli.js:77:3)
           at Module._compile (module.js:449:26)
           at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:467:10)
           at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
           at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
           at Module.require (module.js:362:17)
           at require (module.js:378:17)
           at Object.<anonymous> (/tmp/node-npm-5iGk/cli.js:2:1)
           at Module._compile (module.js:449:26)
       Error: npm doesn't work with node v0.8.2
       Required: node@0.4 || 0.5 || 0.6
           at /tmp/node-npm-5iGk/bin/npm-cli.js:57:23
           at Object.<anonymous> (/tmp/node-npm-5iGk/bin/npm-cli.js:77:3)
           at Module._compile (module.js:449:26)
           at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:467:10)
           at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
           at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
           at Module.require (module.js:362:17)
           at require (module.js:378:17)
           at Object.<anonymous> (/tmp/node-npm-5iGk/cli.js:2:1)
           at Module._compile (module.js:449:26)
       Dependencies installed
-----> Discovering process types
       Procfile declares types -> mongod, redis, web
-----> Compiled slug size is 5.0MB
-----> Launching... done, v9
```

Running "heroku ps" confirms the crash. OK, no problem, so I rolled back the change, added folder *node_module* back to the Git repository and removed it from file *.gitignore*. However, even after reverting, I still get the same error message on deployment, but now the application is running correctly again. Running "heroku ps" tells me the application is running.

What's the right way to do this? Include folder *node_modules* or not?  And why would I still be getting the error message when I roll back? My guess is the Git repository is in a bad state on the Heroku side.

Comment: I am the Node language owner at Heroku and the answer is simple: No. Do not check `node_modules` in to Heroku apps.

Comment: @hunterloftis 'Do not check node_modules **in to**' or 'Do not check node_modules **into**' ? To clarify, as the Node language owner at Heroku, do you want us to upload our entire node_modules via our git push or not?  I prefer not to due to bandwidth waste and the fact that Heroku will get them on the backend of my git push; however, I have had to edit files in my node_modules manually to get Heroku to load my app.  I have therefore had to ignore node_modules minus the whole module that included my edited file to get it to work.

Answer (score 410, accepted):

### Second Update

The FAQ is not available anymore.

From the documentation of [`shrinkwrap`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/shrinkwrap):

> If you wish to lock down the specific bytes included in a package, for example to have 100% confidence in being able to reproduce a deployment or build, then you ought to check your dependencies into source control, or pursue some other mechanism that can verify contents rather than versions.

Shannon and Steven mentioned this before but I think it should be part of the accepted answer.

---

### Update

The source listed for the below recommendation [has been updated](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/faq#should-i-check-my-node-modules-folder-into-git).  They are no longer recommending the `node_modules` folder be committed.

> Usually, no. Allow npm to resolve dependencies for your packages.
>
> For packages you deploy, such as websites and apps, you should use npm
> shrinkwrap to lock down your full dependency tree:
>
> https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/shrinkwrap

---

### Original Post

For reference, npm FAQ answers your question clearly:

> Check node_modules into git for things you deploy, such as websites
> and apps. Do not check node_modules into git for libraries and modules
> intended to be reused. Use npm to manage dependencies in your dev
> environment, but not in your deployment scripts.

and for some good rationale for this, read [Mikeal Rogers' post on this](https://web.archive.org/web/20150116024411/http://www.futurealoof.com/posts/nodemodules-in-git.html).

---

Source: https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/faq#should-i-check-my-node-modules-folder-into-git

Comment: This is not correct - in fact it is very bad idea. If you are developing on Windows then deploying on Linux, you will need to rebuild node_modules when you deploy. Which means - chaos. Lots of modified files, and no idea what to do.

Comment: @user3690202 your deploy script just needs to run `npm rebuild`.

Comment: @Kostia, yeah great idea, except for all the modified files in your working copy that have changed for no reason. Or worse, get into a thrashing situation where the files are changing constantly because unix dev checks in his changed files, then windows checks in his, repeat cycle forever.

Comment: @user3690202 the best approach would be to have all of your development environments be identical. Use vagrant (vagrantup.com).

Comment: That's not possible - some of our devs develop targetting windows, others targetting linux, but the same code base. The best approach would be to not commit node modules - oops.

Comment: @user3690202 Sounds like you have a very unconventional case, rather than the norm, so saying "this is not correct" is probably an overstatement. Having said that, not sure what your exact use case is, but I can't think of any reason for using both windows and linux for development. Stick to one, and run tests or QA on all platforms your support.

Comment: @Kostia Our use case is a pretty common one. We are volunteers and using our own machines, not company ones. Seems like a pretty common situation for open source.

Comment: @Adam tangentially, could you add the files being compiled to `.gitignore`? That way, the source is in git, and any compiled components are not, similarly to how `dist` or `output` folders are gitignored in grunt and gulp projects.

Comment: @Kostia Yes, I think that may be a good in-between. In addition, we use Heroku which caches the sources between releases, so we have some protection there.

Comment: This should be broken down into different answers because the author changed the answer to something completely different. The upvotes are not accurate as anyone who upvoted before the edit would disagree with the edit (the edit is a 180 degree change).

Comment: Spencer, I see your point, but this answer simply mirrors whatever is written on the npm faq. It would have been wrong NOT to update it after the source changed.

Comment: I've been working with node almost exclusively for over a year and this has always bothered me. 

Custom node modules that aren't in NPM won't be tracked. OBVIOUSLY you can track them in other ways but these are major components in your application and (IMHO) should be tracked by your version control system.

Comment: From the npm shrinkwrap page: `If you wish to lock down the specific bytes included in a package, for example to have 100% confidence in being able to reproduce a deployment or build, then you ought to check your dependencies into source control, or pursue some other mechanism that can verify contents rather than versions.`

Comment: Really *really* confused as to why people are talking about windows and unix here ?  How could the platform possible affect the javascript in node_modules ?

Comment: @BenGeorge because some packages like npm version of phantomjs install precompiled binaries based on the platform you're on.

Comment: @Anon thanks :)  I actually learnt that the hard way a few days after posting that comment :D .. npm rebuild fixes it though.

Comment: For those that don't think its a good idea to commit packages: `Or how I obtained direct publish access to 13% of npm packages (including popular ones).
The estimated number of packages potentially reachable through dependency chains is 52%.` 
 https://github.com/ChALkeR/notes/blob/master/Gathering-weak-npm-credentials.md

Comment: Several links are broken (404), e.g. the last one. There isn't any need to keep them and other historical information around (it is still in the revision history). Can you update answer as if it was written today?

Answer (score 174):

My biggest concern with *not* checking folder *node_modules* into Git is that 10 years down the road, when your production application is still in use, npm may not be around. Or npm might become corrupted; or the maintainers might decide to remove the library that you rely on from their repository; or the version you use might be trimmed out.

This can be mitigated with repository managers like [Maven](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Maven), because you can always use your own local [Nexus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nexus#Other_computing_uses) (Sonatype) or [Artifactory](https://jfrog.com/artifactory/) to maintain a mirror with the packages that you use. As far as I understand, such a system doesn't exist for npm. The same goes for client-side library managers like [Bower](https://bower.io/) and [Jam.js](https://github.com/caolan/jam).

If you've committed the files to your own Git repository, then you can update them when you like, and you have the comfort of repeatable builds and the knowledge that your application won't break because of some third-party action.

Comment: Plenty of options today: Nexus (https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/NEXUS-5852), Artifactory (https://www.jfrog.com/jira/browse/RTFACT-5143), npm_lazy (https://github.com/mixu/npm_lazy), npm-lazy-mirror (https://www.npmjs.org/package/npm-lazy-mirror), etc.

Comment: Quote from npmjs FAQ: "If you are paranoid about depending on the npm ecosystem, you should run a private npm mirror or a private cache.". I think this points to the issue you are referring, right?

Comment: A case in point https://developers.slashdot.org/story/16/03/23/0652204/how-one-dev-broke-node-and-thousands-of-projects-in-11-lines-of-javascript

Comment: Npm isn't going to disappear over night, so the benefit doesn't really pair up well with the loss of clarity in your commit history and your huge bundle size. If someone is building an application that they think will still be active in 10 years, it's reasonable to expect that it will receive a lot of maintenance along the way. The point about NPM outages is a much better argument though, although there are probably better ways to mitigate that risk than committing to source.

Comment: Even one month down the road is dangerous if you don't commit your dependencies (preferably in a separate repository though). As I found one morning when I cloned one of my projects and found a package version had been removed from npm. I spent half a day changing all my versions of cascading dependencies to get npm update to work and build again.

Comment: Seems like you had some great foresight here, with npm becoming increasingly unreliable and corporatist. Really wish I would have committed local copies back when I first read this answer, would have saved me a lot of time and money.

Comment: Sadly the original Sinopia no longer works with very new versions of node: https://github.com/rlidwka/sinopia/issues/456 .

Comment: The reason why these are bad reasons to not checkin node_modules is that you should never build an application with the expectation that you're going to let it go out of date and run obsolete modules. If you run an application, you have to keep it modern, or else just turn it off, it's a security risk. To be like, I'm going to checkin my node_modules so I never have to update them is not a good strategy.

Answer (score 69):

You should *not include* folder *node_modules* in your *.gitignore* file (or rather [you *should include* folder *node_modules* in your source](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-nodejs#package-json) deployed to Heroku).

If folder *node_modules*:

- **exists** then `npm install` will use those vendored libraries and will rebuild any binary dependencies with `npm rebuild`.
- **doesn't exist** then `npm install` will have to fetch all dependencies itself which adds time to the slug compile step.

See the Node.js buildpack source for [these exact steps](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-nodejs/blob/master/bin/compile#L171).

However, the original error looks to be an incompatibility between the versions of [npm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Npm_(software)) and Node.js. It is a good idea to always explicitly set the `engines` section of your *packages.json* file according to [this guide](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-versions) to avoid these types of situations:

```json
{
  "name": "myapp",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "engines": {
    "node": "0.8.x",
    "npm":  "1.1.x"
  }
}
```

This will ensure [development/production parity](http://www.12factor.net/dev-prod-parity) and reduce the likelihood of such situations in the future.

Comment: Thanks for the help Ryan.  That got me past the npm version error but now it fails when compiling the redis package.  The error message is "OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Users/Jason/tastemade/tastebase/node_modules/redis-url/node_modules/redis/node_modules/hiredis/build'".  It looks like it's using a path from my local box on the heroku servers.  Are there certain files in the node_modules I need to add to .gitignore?

Comment: I'm not sure what's going on with that particular library, but I'd try excluding node_modules from git in this case and seeing if that helps (forcing npm to fetch everything itself and ensuring a fresh build environment).

Comment: @RyanDaigle Best practice now (Nov 2013) recommended by both npm (https://npmjs.org/doc/faq.html#Should-I-check-my-node_modules-folder-into-git) and heroku (https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-nodejs#package-json) is to check in node_modules to git. Would you update your answer (as it has top billing)?

Comment: While pushing to heroku you'll get the output "-----> Caching node_modules directory for future builds". This is to shorten future slug compilation.

Comment: I have a problem that the node_modules filepath is too long to commit. Git wont find the files.

Comment: This answer led me to `npm update`, which successfully rebuilt `/node_modules`. Hopefully that helps someone else too!

Answer (score 25):

I was going to leave this after this comment: *[Should I check in folder "node_modules" to Git when creating a Node.js app on Heroku?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11459475/should-i-check-in-node-modules-to-git-when-creating-a-node-js-app-on-heroku#comment38119517_19416403)*

But Stack Overflow was formatting it weirdly.

If you don't have identical machines and are checking in node_modules, do a .gitignore on the native extensions. Our .gitignore looks like:

```
# Ignore native extensions in the node_modules folder (things changed by npm rebuild)
node_modules/**/*.node
node_modules/**/*.o
node_modules/**/*.a
node_modules/**/*.mk
node_modules/**/*.gypi
node_modules/**/*.target
node_modules/**/.deps/
node_modules/**/build/Makefile
node_modules/**/**/build/Makefile
```

Test this by first checking everything in, and then have another developer do the following:

```
rm -rf node_modules
git checkout -- node_modules
npm rebuild
git status
```

Ensure that no files changed.

Comment: Just added this. Solved my issue. The windows github kept crashing trying to go over 7000+ node_module files :/

Answer (score 11):

I believe that `npm install` should not run in a production environment. There are several things that can go wrong - npm outage, download of newer dependencies ([shrinkwrap](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/commands/npm-shrinkwrap/) seems to have solved this) are two of them.

On the other hand, folder *node_modules* should not be committed to Git. Apart from their big size, commits including them can become distracting.

The best solutions would be this: `npm install` should run in a [CI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_integration) environment that is similar to the production environment. All tests will run and a zipped release file will be created that will include all dependencies.

Comment: Why would you have a step that runs on CI that wouldn't run as part of your deployment? This means you don't have parity between the 2 systems! As the answer says above - commit the folder just ignore the native extensions, that way you are covered for things like npm outages

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I believe that the node_modules that run in your production server should be generated from an npm install, not from whatever the devs have commited. A dev's node_modules folder does not necessarily match the package.json contents.

Answer (score 10):

I have been using both committing the *node_modules* folder and shrink-wrapping. Both solutions did not make me happy.

In short: a committed *node_modules* folder adds too much noise to the repository.And *shrinkwrap.json* is not easy to manage and there isn't any guarantee that some shrink-wrapped project will build in a few years.

I found that Mozilla was using a separate repository for one of their projects: https://github.com/mozilla-b2g/gaia-node-modules

So it did not take me long to implement this idea in a Node.js CLI tool: https://github.com/bestander/npm-git-lock

Just before every build, add:

```
npm-git-lock --repo [git@bitbucket.org:your/dedicated/node_modules/git/repository.git]
```

It will calculate the hash of your *package.json* file and will either check out folder *node_modules* content from a remote repository, or, if it is a first build for this *package.json* file, will do a clean `npm install` and push the results to the remote repository.

Answer (score 6):

Explicitly adding a npm version to file *package.json* ("npm":  "1.1.x") and *not* checking in folder *node_modules* to Git worked for me.

It may be slower to deploy (since it downloads the packages each time), but I couldn't get the packages to compile when they were checked in. Heroku was looking for files that only existed on my local box.

Comment: In case this is still up for debate, I would take a look at this stackoverflow post which is almost a duplicate of your question above:  

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11459733/check-in-node-modules-vs-shrinkwrap

Basically, it seems the convention is to check in node_modules, and manage your versions of those modules locally.  This seems pretty reasonable, and perhaps the most succinct explanation is this:

http://www.mikealrogers.com/posts/nodemodules-in-git.html

Good luck!

Answer (score 5):

From *["node_modules" in Git](https://web.archive.org/web/20150212165006/http://www.futurealoof.com/posts/nodemodules-in-git.html)*:

> To recap.
>
> - Only checkin node_modules for applications you deploy, not reusable
>   packages you maintain.
> - Any compiled dependencies should have their
>   source checked in, not the compile targets, and should $ npm rebuild
>   on deploy.

My favorite part:

> All you people who added node_modules to your gitignore, **remove that
> shit, today**, it’s an artifact of an era we’re all too happy to leave
> behind. The era of global modules is dead.

<sub>(The original link was [this one](http://www.futurealoof.com/posts/nodemodules-in-git.html), but it is now dead. Thanks @Flavio for pointing it out.)*</sub>

Comment: The site you linked seems to have been let expired and now full of scammy ads. I wish those ads were "artifacts of an era we’d all be too happy to leave behind".

Comment: @FlavioCopes Updated my answer with link from Wayback Machine.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of checking in folder *node_modules*, make a *package.json* file for your application.

The *package.json file* specifies the dependencies of your application. Heroku can then tell npm to install all of those dependencies. The tutorial you linked to contains a section on *package.json* files.

Comment: I do have a package.json.  It has the following:  {
  "name": "node-example",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "2.5.x",
 "redis-url": "0.1.0",
 "mongodb": ">=0.9.9" 
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "0.8.x"
  }
}

Comment: I did on my local box to create the node_modules directory.  That's what I checked in, then removed, then added back.

Comment: After looking at the tutorial more, it seems as though they are committing node_modules. In that case, I'm not sure if there's a way to not commit node_modules. Sorry

Answer (score 4):

I am using this solution:

1. Create a separate repository that holds folder *node_modules*. If you have native modules that should be build for specific platform then create a separate repository for each platform.
2. Attach these repositories to your project repository with `git submodule`:

   `git submodule add .../your_project_node_modules_windows.git node_modules_windows`

   `git submodule add .../your_project_node_modules_linux_x86_64 node_modules_linux_x86_64`
3. Create a link from platform-specific `node_modules` to `node_modules` directory and add `node_modules` to `.gitignore`.
4. Run `npm install`.
5. Commit submodule repository changes.
6. Commit your project repository changes.

So you can easily switch between `node_modules` on different platforms (for example, if you are developing on OS X and deploying to Linux).

Answer (score 4):

**Scenario 1:**

One scenario:

You use a package that gets removed from npm. If you have all the modules in the folder node_modules, then it won't be a problem for you. If you do only have the package name in the package.json, you can't get it anymore.

If a package is less than 24 hours old, you can easily remove it from npm.
If it's older than 24 hours old, then you need to contact them.

But:

> If you contact support, they will check to see if removing that version of your package would break any other installs. If so, we will not remove it.

[read more](https://blog.npmjs.org/post/141905368000/changes-to-npms-unpublish-policy#_=_)

So the chances for this are low, but there is scenario 2...

---

**Scenario 2:**

An other scenario where this is the case:

You develop an enterprise version of your software or a very important software and write in your package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
    "studpid-package": "~1.0.1"
}
```

You use the method `function1(x)`of that package.

Now the developers of studpid-package rename the method `function1(x)`to `function2(x)` and they make a fault...
They change the version of their package from `1.0.1` to `1.1.0`.
That's a problem because when you call `npm install` the next time, you will accept version `1.1.0` because you used the tilde (`"studpid-package": "~1.0.1"`).

Calling `function1(x)` can cause errors and problems now.

---

Pushing the whole node_modules folder (often more than 100 MB) to your repository, will cost you memory space.
A few kb (package.json only) compared with hundreds of MB (package.json & node_modules)... Think about it.

You **could do it / should think about it** if:

- the software is very important.
- it costs you money when something fails.
- you don't trust the npm registry. npm is centralized and could theoretically be shut down.

You **don't need** to publish the node_modules folder in 99.9% of the cases if:

- you develop a software just for yourself.
- you've programmed something and just want to publish the result on GitHub because someone else could maybe be interested in it.

---

If you don't want the node_modules to be in your repository, just create a `.gitignore` file and add the line `node_modules`.

Answer (score 2):

If you're rolling your own modules specific to your application, you can either:

- Keep those (*and only those*) in your application's `/node_modules` folder and move out all the other dependencies to parent `../node_modules` folder. This will work because of how NodeJS CommonJS modules system works by moving up to the parent directory, and so on, until the root of the tree is reached. See: https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html
- Or gitignore all `/node_modules/*` **except** your `/node_modules/your-modules`. See: [Make .gitignore ignore everything except a few files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/987142/make-gitignore-ignore-everything-except-a-few-files)

This use case is pretty awesome. It lets you keep modules you created specifically for your application nicely with it and doesn't clutter with dependencies which can be installed later.