# Grunt & Teamcity

Tags: gruntjs, teamcity-8.0

I'm new to Teamcity and I set it up with grunt to build my webapp. I am using the [jonnyzzz/TeamCity.Node plugin](https://github.com/jonnyzzz/TeamCity.Node) with Teamcity 8.0.5.

All the grunt tasks are installed locally to the project and dependencies are in the node_modules directory. Teamcity sends all files to the agent including the node_modules. Ideally, I would like to not check in node_modules nor send node plugins along to agent. How does one set up Teamcity to transfer project files only to the agent, and the agent would have the node modules already? Maybe I have to install modules globally? Doesn't seem right..

Also, how can I get access to the build number from within grunt? I assume the plugin sends it somehow but did not find where or how...

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

For others looking for the same questions...

As described in the this [blog post](http://blog.jonnyzzz.name/2013/08/nodejs-and-nvm-and-grunt.html) you can access the build number using the plugin.

I also read that adding node_modules is the correct thing to do. Mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11459733/check-in-node-modules-vs-shrinkwrap) and [here](http://www.futurealoof.com/posts/nodemodules-in-git.html)

thanks