# Offline installation of npm package

Tags: node.js, npm, offline

I would like to copy a project folder and install it globally in an offline machine.
The project folder will have a package.json file and all the modules already installed in node_module folder. How can I do it?
Npm link and npm install  won't work (long timeout, trying to connect to the internet).

Thanks

**Edit 1:**
Tried npmbox, the instllation is super slow...I need to find something better...

Comment: Is the machine totally disconnected or just from the internet?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check in node\_modules vs. shrinkwrap](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11459733/check-in-node-modules-vs-shrinkwrap)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install npm package while offline?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43064107/how-to-install-npm-package-while-offline)