# How to install appium thru npm at offline machine

Tags: npm, appium, npm-install

I have installed nodejs with npm, appium guhub package.

My machine does not has Internet connection

How do I use npm to install the appium?

```
Npm install -g appium
```

Is not working.

Comment: Basically your question is not about Appium, but [how to install npm package while offline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43064107/how-to-install-npm-package-while-offline).

Answer (score 0):

Try with this steps

- Create **package.json** file using `npm-init` command
- list all the modules in package.json that you need
- Run `npm-install` on your terminal

full reference : https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/configuring-npm/package-json

Comment: i am not sure this "Create package.json file using npm-init command" , because the appium package downloaded from github https://github.com/appium/appium already has this file.

Comment: are you downloaded the full repo of appium?

Comment: Yes I downloaded full repo of appium.

Comment: for working with appium in nodejs  why you download the repo  ?

Comment: without downloading repo  create one new folder and in the terminal of the foder run`npm init` command it will give you a json file after that follow the steps mentioned in answer it though that you can use the appium package in node js

Comment: I need to install the appium command line version (not desktop UI version) that's my objective. From user guide, I need to run command npm install but my machine isn't Internet machine. So my question is how do I proceed. Your answer isn't clear to me as I'm not sure why I need create package. The github appium has it already. I cannot make use of it? Then last step of your answer is run npm-install. This isn't npm command. The correct one is npm install. Sorry that your answer is not right.

Comment: Did you visit gihubt appium repo see thru the files. There is package.json. All modules was there. Npm install command isn't run if I cmd to the repo path and run npm install appium command.