# How to create an NPM environment for an offline build

Tags: node.js, linux, npm, node-modules

I am trying to do an NPM build, install and bundle on a server which does not have a network connection

I can run the build successfully on an online server, and I can copy the directories which are required over to the offline server

How can I reproduce the NPM environment on the offline server so that an an NPM build, install and bundle will be successful?

I assume I should be copying the `node_modules` and `package-lock.json` and running an `npm install --offline`.

Comment: Have you read e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/43064107/3001761?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I can run the build successfully on an online server, and I can copy the directories which are required over to the offline server

Knowing that, on a system that has access to the internet, run `npm install` to create and populate the `node_modules` directory with all the dependencies.

Copy over the entire application directory including `node_modules` directory, allowing all dependencies available to the offline server.

This is the approach shared in comments: [How to install npm package while offline?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43064107/3001761)

If the dependencies need to be updated, these steps would need to be repeated.