# Share Objectdefinition on Client (Angular) and Server (NodeJs)

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, mean-stack

I am trying to share a specific javascript "object definition" (class) between server and client. On the server I use `Node` with `Express` and on the client `Angular`. (so far no database, therefore not the entire MEAN stack) The objects will be send via `JSON` and `socket.io`.

Example:

```
'use strict';

var Foo = function (fid) {
  this.fid = fid;

  this.toJSON = function () {
    return ('{"fid":"' + this.fid + '"}');
  };

};

Foo.fromJSON = function (json) {
  var obj = JSON.parse(json);
  return new Map(obj.fid);
};
```

For now the `Foo`code is inside a separate file. I guess I need to change my "object definition"? If yes, how? Where do I put it in my project structure? (I use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17005925/1209187) structure.)

thanks

Comment: You do not need to implement `toJSON` explicitly on objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put those class definitions into a file and include into the client with `<script>` and `require` with nodejs.

To achieve this on nodejs you need to pass the class def into the `module.exports` variable, that is only avaiable at nodejs.

```
var Foo = function (fid) {
  this.fid = fid;

  this.toJSON = function () {
    return ('{"fid":"' + this.fid + '"}');
  };    
};

if(module && module.exports)
   module.exports = Foo;
```

Then you can use it in nodejs:

```
Foo = require("foo.js");
var foo = new Foo();
```

This solution works, if you place **every class** in an **own file**.

If you want to have **all classes** in **one file**:

```
var Foo = function (fid) {
  this.fid = fid;

  this.toJSON = function () {
    return ('{"fid":"' + this.fid + '"}');
  };    
};

var Bar = function (fid) {
  this.fid = fid;

  this.toJSON = function () {
    return ('{"fid":"' + this.fid + '"}');
  };

};
if(module && module.exports){
   module.exports.Foo = Foo;
   module.exports.Bar = Bar;
}
```

In you nodejs:

```
var Classes = require("classes.js");
var foo = new Classes.Foo();
```

**Update** due to the question in the comment:

To use the `Foo` inside the `Bar` you need to `require` this in nodejs and in client you dont need anything (global).

```
var Bar = Bar || require("Bar.js");  //if class Bar is undefined, we work on nodejs and need to require the Bar file.

function Foo (){
  var bar = new Bar();
}

if(module && module.exports){
  module.exports.Foo = Foo;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. For now I only tested the import on the server side, but I stumbled upon a new "problem". Based on your example, what if I want to use 'Bar' inside 'Foo' (seperate files)? I could check for "module" or "module.exports" and add the dependency based on the result, or is there a better way?

Comment: i would build a method, that does return the required class. See my update

Comment: Thanks again. Now I also tried using it on the client, but I see "Uncaught ReferenceError: module is not defined" in the console. I understand why "module" is not defined on the client, but I tought "if(module)" would prefend the output.         '(function (module) {
  if (module && module.exports) {
    module.exports = Foo;
  }
}());' that works, but is this the correct way?

Comment: maybe check `typeof module != "undefined"`

Comment: I checked "module !== undefined" but that didn't work. Yours on the other hand does work, kinda weird (at least for me) but thanks.