# Simple architecture for AngularJS, Express and node

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, express, cassandra

I'm trying to learn nodeJS by developping a simple site managing an account and allowing a user to add collections of books.

I chose Cassandra to hold data, but should I create Column family containing the user and each of his books/magasine collections ? or should I create a column family for he user, and a column family containing all collections from different user (as I would do in a relationnal database).

```
Map<RowKey, {id_user, XXXXX}, 
    {email, xxxx@mail.org}, 
    {magasine_collection, Map<id, collection>},
    {book_collection, Map<id, collection>}
```

My app has 2 pages, one for managing account (change email, add collection type), and anoher page with a tab in wich I want to display all newly added collection from various user in realtime and a form for all the user to add items to their collections.

Is this app achievable using Cassandra, express and AngularJS, or should I use other frameworks ?

I was thinking to use a MEAN directory structure  (without mongoDB) as described by the second answer of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13998793/structuring-a-nodejs-and-angular-js-app), but as I have a single page layout with different content depending on the page (user account or tab with collections), where should I place the layout.html if my content partials are in /public/views/ ?