# AngularJS HTML templates are routing failed in Nodejs/Expressjs

Tags: angularjs, node.js

I am working on a small AngularJS project. I used ui-router to route different html templates which works fine. The code and folder structure shows as below:

```
var app = angular.module('flapperNews', ['ui.router']);
app.config([
'$stateProvider',
'$urlRouterProvider',
function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $stateProvider
      .state('news', {
          url: '/news',
          templateUrl: 'news.html',
          controller: 'MainCtrl'
      })
    .state('posts', {
        url: '/posts/{id}',
        templateUrl: 'posts.html',
        controller: 'PostsCtrl'
    });

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('news');
}]);
```

Folder Structure:
[image]

However, when I tried to install them into the Nodejs/Expressjs, it shows the error: GET http://localhost:3000/news.html 404 (Not Found)

[image]

I have already put all html templates into the views folder shows as below, but doesn't work. I am new to NodeJS, anyone knows what happened? Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: Can you show your `app.js` file? in which folder all you `html` files exists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put all your `HTML` files in `public` folder and access all from there. Since `Angular` unable to get that pages from `views` folder since it's server side stuff.
Putting `HTML` files in `public` folder is not a standard but it's mostly used while using `Angular`

You can get more ideas from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13998793/structuring-a-nodejs-and-angular-js-app) with `Jess` answer

Comment: Thank you so much! It works! I created a new folder named templates under the public folder and changed the path in angularApp to:templateUrl: '/templates/news.html' It worked.

Comment: Glad to help you :)

Comment: Thank you @abdulbarik  Like you said, eventually, I created a new folder named: templates under the public folder and put all my html templates into that folder, changed the angular path to templateUrl: '/templates/news.html' Finally, it worked!

Comment: @abdulbarik it was a opposite case for me. My html files were inside public/templates/ and my routing was not working properly but when i moved my html files to root/views/ it started working perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need `/views/home.html` in your `templateUrl:` and the `views` folder should be inside your `public` directory.

I assume you have something close to `app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));` somewhere?  This is setting you up to display static files from within the `public` directory.

Comment: thank you so much! The logic is correct, but after I moved views folder to public folder, it give me error: Error: Failed to lookup view "error" in views directory ". Eventually, I created a new folder named: templates under the public folder and put all my html templates into that folder, changed the angular path to templateUrl: '/templates/news.html' Finally, it worked! Thank you so much!