# Missing npm dependency - how it affects on app

Tags: npm, static-site, hexo

I consider to use Hexo (the static blog generator) based on npm. I wonder one thing, what if although one npm package (dependency) will not be longer available? Each package has its own author and it can cancel support or completely remove it from npm's repository at any time.
So what do I do if missing one of the npm package affect on running Hexo and consequently I'll not be able to generate my blog in the future?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although this can happen (and happened at least once), it is not a serious problem ussually. While you will be waiting until somebody will fix the missing dependency (it take place quickly on popular packages like Hexo) you can use older working version. And if you want to be 100% sure, you can commit node_modules together with your web sources ([see discussion here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18128863/should-node-modules-folder-be-included-in-the-git-repository/)).