# Angular 4 project too large on disk

Tags: angular, npm

I found out that my Angular 4 project is around 300 MB on disk. I also figured out that the folder node_modules is the culprit for this size. Should I keep this folder out of the repository to save repository space and avoid long data traffic when updating source files on a repository?
Thanks a lot.

[image]

Comment: the node_modules folder is ignored by default in most .gitignore configs

Comment: this is a dup of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18128863/should-node-modules-folder-be-included-in-the-git-repository/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`node_modules` should be ignored when the project is uploaded to CVS, doing the opposite defies the purpose of a package manager.

While [`package-lock.json`](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package-lock.json) (introduced in NPM 5) should be commited, it locks currently installed dependencies and allows to replicate the state of `node_modules` on `npm i`.