# How to make `npm install` libraries persistent when using git?

Tags: git, npm, webpack

I'm scaffolding the `vue` app `frontend` using `webpack`:

```
vue init webpack frontend
cd frontend
```

For this app, I need - among others - `axios`, hence:

```
npm install axios
```

Now I push the code to the repo and clone the repo from another computer.

My **question** is:

How do I make sure all the required npm libraries are there on the new computer so that `npm run build` succeeds?

Comment: Check in the `node_modules` folder. Though I would [recommend against it for various reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18128863/should-node-modules-folder-be-included-in-the-git-repository)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you check out the repo on a new system, you will run

```
npm install
```

to fetch all the `node_modules` associated with the project. Make sure your `package-lock.json` was checked into git so that you will be guaranteed to fetch the exact same versions as were intended in the commit.

Comment: Good answer, but I believe OP needs to add `--save` to their `npm install axios` call to get it to show up in `package-lock.json`.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I did a research and found: "as of npm 5.0.0 `--save` is the default", see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19578796/what-is-the-save-option-for-npm-install

Comment: For the difference between checking in `package-lock.json` and `package.json` see Xin's answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44206782/do-i-commit-the-package-lock-json-file-created-by-npm-5