# How to reduce node_module file size

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm, npm-install

I am working on 2-3 react apps, and for each app when I run `npm install`, it installs a bunch of dependencies in the **"node-module"** folder which is approximately 250-300mb in size! It becomes really hard to deploy that on Github. Is there any way to reduce file size of node_module folder.

Comment: why do you push your node modules folder to github? Include them in your `.gitignore` file

Comment: Use less dependencies? But what is the actual issue here? What specific problem does the size cause?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Should "node\_modules" folder be included in the git repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18128863/should-node-modules-folder-be-included-in-the-git-repository)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to push node modules to github, they should be included in your .gitignore file.

Within the root directory, edit `.gitignore` and add the line

> node_modules/

Now when you push to github, the node_modules directory will be ignored.

Comment: If something is added to a Git repo, it first has to be removed. Adding to .gitignore just means it cannot be added it it never was.