# Cannot push my React project to Github, file size exceeds file size of 100.00MB

Tags: reactjs, git, github

I have an error when trying to push my React app onto Github. First I created the repository in Github. Then, I added the remote repository using `git remote add origin <repo name>`. Then I added and commit the files. Lastly I tried `git push -u origin main`. I got the following error:

```
remote: error: File node_modules/.cache/default-development/0.pack is 153.50 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB
remote: error: File node_modules/.cache/default-development/4.pack is 131.01 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB
remote: error: File node_modules/.cache/default-development/2.pack is 131.43 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB
remote: error: File node_modules/.cache/default-production/0.pack is 131.55 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB
remote: error: File node_modules/.cache/default-development/9.pack is 131.12 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB
```

I do not understand how it would exceed the limit as I have created two other React apps with more code in the past and uploaded them the same way to Github. The only difference I can think of is that this project uses Tailwind Css and Firebase. How can I reduce the size of `node_modules/.cache/default-development/9.pack` or even find what the file is?

Comment: You should not commit `node_modules` into Git. You only want to commit the package lockfile. https://stackoverflow.com/q/18128863/2954547. Unfortunately these large files are now embedded in Git history and will need to be removed with a tool like BFG Repo Cleaner. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bfg-repo-cleaner.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No need to push node_modules in git
delete node_module then push it and then
Just make a file `.gitignore` in the same directory where `package.json` and write

```
/node_modules
```

then try to push it
and then you can run `npm install`

Comment: `node_modules` has already been committed so `.gitignore` is not enough.

Comment: I know that he needs to delete node_module then push it and then he needs to add .gitignore

Comment: I edited the answer please remove your downvote and if you like it please upvote it means a lot

Comment: "*…delete node_module…*" Not enough just to delete and commit — `node_module` stays in previous commit(s). One needs to remove `node_module` from all previous commit(s) and that a bit harder then just "delete and push".

Comment: yeah but node_module is in last 10 commits then it's better to not delete the last commits just delete them from now onwards

Comment: In that case large files are still in the previous commits and GitHub would not allow to push. "*…better to not delete the last commits…*" I never say anything about deleting commits, only about deleting large files from the previous commits.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241003/discussion-between-phd-and-jay-patel).

Answer (score 2):

In my experience, it is crucial to include this line in .gitignore

```
# eslint cache
.eslintcache
```

in addition to /node_modules (as mentioned by others). This prevents the *.pack cache files from being pushed which are very very large (at least in my case). This solved my problem. I hope it will be of help to others.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing to worry , just go to your Project folder --> right click anywhere and check if show hidden files  checked --> now you see a .git folder --> just delete that -> and thats it your problem is solved

create repo again with git init ........

Answer (score 0):

For me, I just deleted .next from the GitHub repository.
Add '/.next' in the git ignore file.
Pull the repository again.
install npm