# Check Node Modules into Git for New Branches

Tags: node.js, git, git-submodules, gitignore, branching-and-merging

I am using Node and Grunt to watch files and compile my stylus css preprocessor code.  Node is otherwise not necessary for this project.

Right now the node_modules folder is not checked into my git repository which is fine for release.   The problem I have is whenever I create a feature branch, node_modules is not there and I can't watch or compile my stylus files.

Is there a way for node_modules to appear in new branches without adding them to .git?  I'd rather not do an npm install on every new branch.

Or is it best practice to add node_modules to git?

If I'd like to add them to git, should I add node_modules as a git submodule?  If adding as a submodule, what url should be specified if any?

The best discussion I've seen about a similar situation is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11459475/should-i-check-in-node-modules-to-git-when-creating-a-node-js-app-on-heroku).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not using `npm` actively, you don't have to do `npm install` on every new branch, you can just do it once, add `node_modules` folder to Git and commit the dependencies to the `master` (the same [way they recommend for frontend dependencies and Bower](http://bower.io/#using-a-different-name-and-a-specific-version-of-a-package)).

I wouldn't recommend you adding `node_modules` as a submodule: usually a submodule is a somewhat self-sufficient component that should/can be developed separately, which is clearly not the case here.

Comment: Thanks.  That's what I did.  Also, since npm dependencies are managed by package.json, it doesn't make sense to create a submodule.