# PhpStorm / WebStorm node_modules and package.json

Tags: node.js, npm, phpstorm, webstorm

Some related questions:

First, I am using PhpStorm 9.0.2 and would like to move the node_modules package directory from the root directory of my project to a sub-directory.  But when I try to do this all of the packages I have installed no longer show up in the "Node.js and NPM" settings page.  I can't seem to find where to set the path, is this even something that is possible to do?

Second, I notice that my package.json file has a few dependencies in it, perhaps the defaults from when my project was set up.  But most of the Node.js packages I've installed since then don't show up.  Is there a way in PhpStorm or otherwise to make sure package.json is automatically kept sync'ed with the packages I currently have installed?  That is what seems to happen with bower.json and my client-side packages.

Third, I would also like to move package.json to a sub-directory, can I do this somehow?

Comment: node_modules and package.json should remain in root and installing packages with the --save flag saves them to your package.json file

Comment: Just to clarify, are you saying there is no way to move node_modules and package.json?  Or just that the recommended way is to keep them in root?

Comment: I like having my Node.js code in a sub-directory called `src` (with the `node_modules` folder and `package.json` in that directory). That way I can have build files, dockerfile, .jshintrc, .gitignore, etc. in the root directory while keeping my Node.js "clean" in its own folder. However I haven't figured out how to tell WebStorm how my project is structured.

Answer (score 1):

The `node_modules` directory is always located right next to the `package.json`. As long as you move both into the same subdirectory, things might be OK depending on how/where you run the Node.js code from.

Personally though, I don't understand why you would want to move only the `node_modules` directory. Based on various resources ([such as this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11459475/should-i-check-in-node-modules-to-git-when-creating-a-node-js-app-on-heroku)) it's recommended to not check-in the `node_modules` directory. In your IDE you can also exclude this folder so it's no longer shown in the file browser window.

For your last question, when executing `npm install xxx`, the dependency is not saved into your `package.json` file. In order to save it, add the `--save` (or `--save-dev` for test dependencies) flag at the end of the install statement: `npm install xxx --save`.

Comment: Thanks @xaviert for your answer and sorry for my delayed response.  It is not so much that I want to hide node_modules, I still like to get into it from time to time.  Rather I have organized my project into a feature-by-feature folder organization, with "client" and "server" sub-folders as the next level folders under each feature name.  So I thought it would be consistent to move my bower and node_modules folders to live underneat a /lib top-level directory.  But I can't figure out how to do that, at least in my JetBrains IDE.