# error running 'npm run dist' to build bootstrap4

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, npm, bootstrap-4

I downloaded and extracted Bootstrap 4 today and am getting an error:

**Setup**

```
pwd
/Volumes/projects/bs4_temp/bootstrap-4.0.0
kevin $ dir
total 1432
drwxr-xr-x  14 kevin  staff   16384 28 May 15:36 .
drwxr-xr-x   8 kevin  staff   16384 29 May 15:15 ..
-rwxr-xr-x   1 kevin  staff     313 18 Jan 09:29 .babelrc.js
-rwxr-xr-x   1 kevin  staff     208 18 Jan 09:29 .editorconfig
-rwxr-xr-x   1 kevin  staff      56 18 Jan 09:29 .eslintignore
-rwxr-xr-x   1 kevin  staff    7123 18 Jan 09:29 .eslintrc.json
-rwxr-xr-x   1 kevin  staff     359 18 Jan 09:29 .gitattributes
drwxr-xr-x   2 kevin  staff   16384 18 Jan 09:29 .github
-rwxr-xr-x   1 kevin  staff     517 18 Jan 09:29 .gitignore
-rwxr-xr-x   1 kevin  staff      45 18 Jan 09:29 .stylelintignore
-rwxr-xr-x   1 kevin  staff    6685 18 Jan 09:29 .stylelintrc
-rwxr-xr-x   1 kevin  staff     782 18 Jan 09:29 .travis.yml
-rwxr-xr-x   1 kevin  staff      17 18 Jan 09:29 CNAME
-rwxr-xr-x   1 kevin  staff    3217 18 Jan 09:29 CODE_OF_CONDUCT.md
-rwxr-xr-x   1 kevin  staff     199 18 Jan 09:29 Gemfile
-rwxr-xr-x   1 kevin  staff    1905 18 Jan 09:29 Gemfile.lock
-rwxr-xr-x   1 kevin  staff    1131 18 Jan 09:29 LICENSE
-rwxr-xr-x   1 kevin  staff    9138 18 Jan 09:29 README.md
-rwxr-xr-x   1 kevin  staff    2505 18 Jan 09:29 _config.yml
drwxr-xr-x   2 kevin  staff   16384 18 Jan 09:29 _data
drwxr-xr-x   3 kevin  staff   16384 18 Jan 09:29 _includes
drwxr-xr-x   2 kevin  staff   16384 18 Jan 09:29 _layouts
drwxr-xr-x   2 kevin  staff   16384 18 Jan 09:29 _plugins
drwxr-xr-x   7 kevin  staff   16384 18 Jan 09:29 assets
drwxr-xr-x   2 kevin  staff   16384 18 Jan 09:29 build
-rwxr-xr-x   1 kevin  staff     744 18 Jan 09:29 composer.json
drwxr-xr-x   4 kevin  staff   16384 18 Jan 09:29 dist
drwxr-xr-x   3 kevin  staff   16384 18 Jan 09:29 docs
-rwxr-xr-x   1 kevin  staff    5430 18 Jan 09:29 favicon.ico
-rwxr-xr-x   1 kevin  staff    4384 18 Jan 09:29 index.html
drwxr-xr-x   5 kevin  staff   16384 18 Jan 09:29 js
drwxr-xr-x   2 kevin  staff   16384 18 Jan 09:29 nuget
-rwxr-xr-x   1 kevin  staff  433474 18 Jan 09:29 package-lock.json
-rwxr-xr-x   1 kevin  staff     530 18 Jan 09:29 package.js
-rwxr-xr-x   1 kevin  staff    9152 18 Jan 09:29 package.json
-rwxr-xr-x   1 kevin  staff     123 18 Jan 09:29 robots.txt
-rwxr-xr-x   1 kevin  staff     249 18 Jan 09:29 sache.json
drwxr-xr-x   4 kevin  staff   16384 18 Jan 09:29 scss
-rwxr-xr-x   1 kevin  staff     114 18 Jan 09:29 sw.js

kevin $ npm --version
6.1.0
```

**The error**

```
kevin $ npm run dist

> bootstrap@4.0.0 dist /Volumes/projects/bs4_temp/bootstrap-4.0.0
> npm-run-all --parallel css js

sh: npm-run-all: command not found
npm ERR! file sh
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall spawn
npm ERR! bootstrap@4.0.0 dist: `npm-run-all --parallel css js`
npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the bootstrap@4.0.0 dist script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
npm WARN Local package.json exists, but node_modules missing, did you mean to install?

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/kevin/.npm/_logs/2018-05-29T16_20_07_838Z-debug.log
```

**Observations**

*[Ignore this:  I believe the current version is 4.1 yet despite looking and trying several times, I seem to be downloading 4.0.0 each time I try. ]*

Edit - downloaded 4.1.1 from another computer. This gives same error and also does not have the node_modules dir.

I last looked at this on Feb (at v4.0.0)and running the same NPM command in that older directory works. Comparing the two directories, the one I used in Feb has a *node_modules* sub dir and the current ZIP does not (nor does the git appear to have one).

Is this my problem, and if so why is *node_modules* missing from the ZIP file today?

Comment: Run `npm install`, the node_modules folder will be created

Comment: See here why it's not included: https://stackoverflow.com/q/11459475/8918893

Comment: Thanks, works with npm install. If you like to make that an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally [it's not recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11459475/8918893) to include node_modules when publishing to the web.

Instead users are expected to install the packages using NPM (in this case). Just run **`npm install`**, and NPM will create the folder for you.

*Ps. NPM finds the module list from package.json*