# Express, Heroku, Postgres declaration: Pool is not a constructor

Tags: database, postgresql, express, heroku, constructor

I'm very confused. This code works on my collaborator's computer, but not mine. We are running the same Heroku work space. I literally just copied his entire last push.

```
const express = require("express");
const path = require("path");
var parser = require("body-parser");
// heroku has an environment variable
// that determines port
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;
// pool controls connections to the postgres db
const { Pool } = require("pg");
const { SSL_OP_SSLEAY_080_CLIENT_DH_BUG } = require("constants");
const pool = new Pool({
  connectionString:
    "postgres://{heroku pg database URL}",
  ssl: {
    rejectUnauthorized: false,
  },
});

app = express();

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.status(200);
    res.send('Hello World');
  });

app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(
      "Server running at https://rateyourgames.heroku.com/ using port" + PORT
    );
    console.log(process.DATABASE_URL);
  });
```

It gives me this error:

```
C:\Users\matth\Full-Stack-Project\src\test.js:10
const pool = new Pool({
             ^

TypeError: Pool is not a constructor
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\matth\Full-Stack-Project\src\test.js:10:14)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1201:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1221:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1050:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:938:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:71:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47
```

Update: I discovered that my version of pg does not match the dependency
my pg is version 6.14.5 and the dependency is `"^8.3.0"`
I tried running `npm i -g pg@8.3.0`, but even though the console says the package updated, it is still saying I have version 6.14.5.

Comment: You've just leaked your database credentials. If those are your real credentials you should invalidate them **_immediately_**. They are forever compromised, and you need to generate new ones. Editing them out of your question is _**not enough**_.

Comment: "I discovered that my version of pg does not match the dependency"—is your `package-lock.json` tracked? Are your `node_modules/` tracked? What command are you running to install dependencies?

Comment: Thanks, I'll change them. Fortunately it's just a school project database that's mostly empty except for a few video games

Comment: I use npm i -g <package name>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `npm i -g` for project dependencies.

`-g` is the [global flag](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/folders#node-modules), so dependencies are installed either system-wide or user-wide. For application dependencies you should install dependencies to the `node_modules/` folder *in the project directory*.

To install a *new* dependency, run something like

```
npm install pg
```

This adds `pg` to your project's `dependencies` in your `package.json`. It also updates your `package-lock.json`. Both of these files should ([probably](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44206782/354577)) be committed, and your `node_modules/` directory should ([probably](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11459475/354577)) be ignored.

If you're not installing a new dependency, but rather just want to install all of a project's dependencies, simply run

```
npm install
```