# How come when I update a few files I end up getting several hundred when trying to merge?

Tags: github

I'm currently using GitHub to manage a project and am relatively new to it. I have a main branch where I hold my production code and secondary branches that are used to manage new features. However, I've noticed that when I finish a feature and then merge it back in I end up getting something like 800 files staged instead of the maybe 10 files I actually added. Why is this and how do I manage it? If it's important I am using VSC and merging my branches through it.

Comment: Line endings misconfigured?

Comment: @bobah Fair point I haven't considered that. However, the majority of the files are small files buried inside of my node_modules.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Should I check in folder "node\_modules" to Git when creating a Node.js app on Heroku?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11459475/should-i-check-in-folder-node-modules-to-git-when-creating-a-node-js-app-on-he)

Comment: You should not be committing `node_modules`.  ["folder node_modules should not be committed to Git. Apart from their big size, commits including them can become distracting."](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29940065/1726083)