# Deploy React App to Azure Web App - "There is not enough space on the disk"

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-webapps

I'm trying to deploy my react app for the first time via GitHub Actions, however, I get the following error in the "Deploy to Azure Web App" phase:

> Package deployment using ZIP Deploy initiated.
>
> Fetching changes.
>
> Cleaning up temp folders from previous zip deployments and extracting
> pushed zip file C:\local\Temp\zipdeploy\z0e1gika.zip (191.73 MB) to
> C:\local\Temp\zipdeploy\extracted
>
> There is not enough space on the disk.\r\n
>
> Error: Failed to deploy web package to App Service.
>
> Error: Deployment Failed, Package deployment using ZIP Deploy failed.
> Refer logs for more details.

In the "Download Artifact From Build Job" phase, I get a warning that there are over 40,000 files and that I should archive unnecessary files. I have a strong suspicion it is due to this - if so, I'm not sure how I can go about identifying and removing unnecessary files.

I also checked the max storage of my app through AzurePortal, which under File System Storage states that I have a 1 GiB threshold. It seems like even with such a large amount of artifacts, it should still be able to handle it, so I'm not sure what's going on.

Comment: Having 40,000 files under source control is objectively **a lot** - what all is in there exactly? What’s the uncompressed size of your repo?

Comment: I found that the files mostly originate from node_modules - I made a google doc that lists everything out:  
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1czQBh6BwybA8IsnEfK1ZSKx-k4UVWO4kBuZEZ3UNidw/edit?usp=sharing

I tried to check the size of my repo through Powershell, but the length column is blank for some reason.

Comment: [`node_modules` isn’t meant to be checked in to version control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11459475/should-i-check-in-folder-node-modules-to-git-when-creating-a-node-js-app-on-he). Your build tool should instead download the dependencies at build time.

Comment: Regardless, you may have to bump to the next pricing level for Azure Web Apps if your expanded app is > 1 GB in size including dependencies.

Comment: @Nikoloz97 You only need to upload the `build` folder for react app. in the `.yml` file change `path` to `path: build/` in the `actions/upload-artifact@v3` section.
 if the OS is Linux then add command in the startup command in configuration as `pm2 serve /home/site/wwwroot --spa --no-daemon`

for reference check this document by [Edison Garcia](https://azureossd.github.io/2022/02/07/React-Deployment-on-App-Service-Linux/)

Comment: @Edison Garcia That worked, thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @[Edison Garcia](https://azureossd.github.io/2022/02/07/React-Deployment-on-App-Service-Linux/) for the blog.

You can use only the `Build` folder for deployment on the web app.
which is created from the command available in the `.yml` file
`npm run build --if present`

**`Deployment`:**

[image]

[image]

**Make changes in the `.yml` file: `path: build/`**

**`main_reactappgithub.yml`:**

```yaml
name: Build and deploy a Node.js app to the Azure Web App - Reactappgithub

on:  
push:  
branches:  
- main  
workflow_dispatch:

jobs:  
build:  
runs-on: ubuntu-latest

steps:  
- uses: actions/checkout@v4

- name: Set up Node.js version  
uses: actions/setup-node@v3  
with:  
node-version: '18.x'

- name: npm install, build, and test  
run: |  
npm install  
npm run build --if-present  
npm run test --if-present

- name: Upload artifact for deployment job  
uses: actions/upload-artifact@v3  
with:  
name: node-app  
path: build/

deploy:  
runs-on: ubuntu-latest  
needs: build  
environment:  
name: 'Production'  
url: ${{ steps.deploy-to-webapp.outputs.webapp-url }}

steps:  
- name: Download artifact from build job  
uses: actions/download-artifact@v3  
with:  
name: node-app

- name: 'Deploy to Azure Web App'  
id: deploy-to-webapp  
uses: azure/webapps-deploy@v2  
with:  
app-name: 'Reactappgithub'  
slot-name: 'Production'  
publish-profile: ${{ secrets.AZUREAPPSERVICE_PUBLISHPROFILE_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx }}  
package: .
```

[image]

[image]

After deployment is complete, we need to make changes in the web app configuration as below.

**`linux`**

- Go to **configuration -> startup command**
- Add `pm2 serve /home/site/wwwroot --spa --no-daemon`

[image]

**`Windows`:**
**No changes**

**`OUTPUT`:**

[image]