# What's the difference between dependencies, devDependencies, and peerDependencies in NPM package.json file?

Tags: node.js, npm, dependencies, package.json

[This documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json) answers my question very poorly. I didn't understand those explanations. Can someone say in simpler words? Maybe with examples if it's hard to choose simple words?

Also added `peerDependencies`, which is closely related and might cause confusion.

Comment: Note there are also [`optionalDependencies`](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#optionaldependencies) now.

Comment: @AidanFeldman "optionalDependencies" is my oxymoron of the day

Comment: npm documentation says: 

"dependencies": Packages required by your application in production.
"devDependencies": Packages that are only needed for local development and testing. see link: https://docs.npmjs.com/specifying-dependencies-and-devdependencies-in-a-package-json-file

Comment: dependencies are the package references that are used by your library without which it cannot work and to be installed along with your library installation automatically.
While looking at peerDependencies, npm will just throw a warning message in case the specified packages are not found in node modules. It will not install any package for you. For detailed explaination refer link: https://medium.com/p/16f43d6c7e45

Answer (score 3228, accepted):

Summary of important behavior differences:

- [`dependencies`](https://github.com/npm/npm/blob/2e3776bf5676bc24fec6239a3420f377fe98acde/doc/files/package.json.md#dependencies) are installed on both:

  - `npm install` from a directory that contains `package.json`
  - `npm install $package` on any other directory
- [`devDependencies`](https://github.com/npm/npm/blob/2e3776bf5676bc24fec6239a3420f377fe98acde/doc/files/package.json.md#devdependencies) are:

  - also installed on `npm install` on a directory that contains `package.json`, unless you pass the `--production` flag (go upvote [Gayan Charith's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31229205/895245)), or if the `NODE_ENV=production` environment variable is set
  - not installed on `npm install "$package"` on any other directory, unless you give it the `--dev` option.
  - are not installed transitively.
- [`peerDependencies`](https://github.com/npm/npm/blob/2e3776bf5676bc24fec6239a3420f377fe98acde/doc/files/package.json.md#peerdependencies):

  - before 3.0: are always installed if missing, and raise an error if multiple incompatible versions of the dependency would be used by different dependencies.
  - [expected to start on 3.0](http://blog.npmjs.org/post/110924823920/npm-weekly-5) (untested): give a warning if missing on `npm install`, and you have to solve the dependency yourself manually. When running, if the dependency is missing, you get an error (mentioned by [@nextgentech](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1997767/nextgentech)) This explains it nicely: https://flaviocopes.com/npm-peer-dependencies/
  - [in version 7](https://github.blog/2021-02-02-npm-7-is-now-generally-available/) peerDependencies are automatically installed unless an upstream dependency conflict is present that cannot be automatically resolved
- Transitivity (mentioned by [Ben Hutchison](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18875674/whats-the-difference-between-dependencies-devdependencies-and-peerdependencies/22004559#comment57650997_22004559)):

  - `dependencies` are installed transitively: if A requires B, and B requires C, then C gets installed, otherwise, B could not work, and neither would A.
  - `devDependencies` is not installed transitively. E.g. we don't need to test B to test A, so B's testing dependencies can be left out.

Related options not discussed here:

- `bundledDependencies` which is discussed on the following question: *[Advantages of bundledDependencies over normal dependencies in npm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11207638/advantages-of-bundleddependencies-over-normal-dependencies-in-npm?lq=1)*
- [`optionalDependencies`](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#optionaldependencies) (mentioned [by Aidan Feldman](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18875674/whats-the-difference-between-dependencies-devdependencies-and-peerdependencies/22004559#comment62749434_18875674))

### devDependencies

`dependencies` are required to run, `devDependencies` only to develop, e.g.: unit tests, CoffeeScript to JavaScript transpilation, minification, ...

If you are going to develop a package, you download it (e.g. via `git clone`), go to its root which contains `package.json`, and run:

```
npm install
```

Since you have the actual source, it is clear that you want to develop it, so by default, both `dependencies` (since you must, of course, run to develop) and `devDependency` dependencies are also installed.

If however, you are only an end user who just wants to install a package to use it, you will do from any directory:

```
npm install "$package"
```

In that case, you normally don't want the development dependencies, so you just get what is needed to use the package: `dependencies`.

If you really want to install development packages in that case, you can set the `dev` configuration option to `true`, possibly from the command line as:

```
npm install "$package" --dev
```

The option is `false` by default since this is a much less common case.

### peerDependencies

(Tested before 3.0)

Source: https://nodejs.org/en/blog/npm/peer-dependencies/

With regular dependencies, you can have multiple versions of the dependency: it's simply installed inside the `node_modules` of the dependency.

E.g. if `dependency1` and `dependency2` both depend on `dependency3` at different versions the project tree will look like:

```
root/node_modules/
                 |
                 +- dependency1/node_modules/
                 |                          |
                 |                          +- dependency3 v1.0/
                 |
                 |
                 +- dependency2/node_modules/
                                            |
                                            +- dependency3 v2.0/
```

Plugins, however, are packages that normally don't require the other package, which is called the *host* in this context. Instead:

- plugins are required *by the host*
- plugins offer a standard interface that the host expects to find
- only the host will be called directly by the user, so there must be a single version of it.

E.g. if `dependency1` and `dependency2` peer depend on `dependency3`, the project tree will look like:

```
root/node_modules/
                 |
                 +- dependency1/
                 |
                 +- dependency2/
                 |
                 +- dependency3 v1.0/
```

This happens even though you never mention `dependency3` in your `package.json` file.

I think this is an instance of the [Inversion of Control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control) design pattern.

A prototypical example of peer dependencies is Grunt, the host, and its plugins.

For example, on a Grunt plugin like https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-uglify, you will see that:

- `grunt` is a `peer-dependency`
- the only `require('grunt')` is under `tests/`: it's not actually used by the program.

Then, when the user will use a plugin, he will implicitly require the plugin from the `Gruntfile` by adding a `grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify')` line, but it's `grunt` that the user will call directly.

This would not work then if each plugin required a different Grunt version.

### Manual

I think the documentation answers the question quite well, maybe you are just not familiar enough with node / other package managers. I probably only understand it because I know a bit about Ruby bundler.

The key line is:

> These things will be installed when doing npm link or npm install from the root of a package and can be managed like any other npm configuration parameter. See npm-config(7) for more on the topic.

And then under npm-config(7) find `dev`:

```
Default: false
Type: Boolean

Install dev-dependencies along with packages.
```

Comment: How does npm distinguish 'install all dependencies specified in package.json' and 'install the package called package from the public registry' when using `npm install package`?

Comment: Ah. I see I've misunderstood. Your answer reads as though `npm install package` is a command you'd use to install all packages that are not dev dependencies, rather than what I now think you meant, which was 'install the package called [package]', which was how I thought it worked before reading this. If I were you I'd edit to say [package-name] which clearly shows that what you mean is 'insert-name-here'.

Comment: This is great! I never realized, but this answer has taught me that the dependencies vs devDependencies difference is only applicable if you're going to publish an npm package. If you're just working on an application or site, it shouldn't matter too much. Thanks!

Comment: what does "$package" syntax mean, with the $ ?

Comment: @MSSucks it's the Bash notation for a variable, nothing specific to NPM. You could write: `package="mypkg"; echo "$package";`. I strongly recommend that you spend some time learning Bash ;)

Comment: This post should be updated to reflect the changed `peerDependencies` behavior in the upcoming npm@3.  From http://blog.npmjs.org/post/110924823920/npm-weekly-5: "We won’t be automatically downloading the peer dependency anymore. Instead, we’ll warn you if the peer dependency isn’t already installed. This requires you to resolve peerDependency conflicts yourself, manually, but in the long run this should make it less likely that you’ll end up in a tricky spot with your packages’ dependencies."

Comment: @nextgentech thanks for the heads up! I have added a small comment for the future version, and when it comes out I will try out and incorporate fully.

Comment: what the heck do you mean by "npm install $package on any other directory"...I can't infer the words missing to explain your half sentence here

Comment: @WeDoTDD Maybe the list format got in the way. The full sentence is: "dependencies are installed on both npm install from a directory that contains package.json and npm install $package on any other directory (that does not contain package.json)". Do you understand now?

Comment: I think dependencies/devDependencies are for the most part one and the same. For example, `webpack`. It's a dev dep but when I deploy, I will need it to create the bundle. Hence, it should be a regular dep.

Comment: Also, devDependencies are not installed transitively by dependent packages. Example: package A depends on package B. Package B depends on package C, and B also devDepends on package D. If you run `npm install` from package A, you will get B and C but not D.

Comment: `npm install` doesn't always install devdependencies even without `--production` flag (I think it's an npm bug). In this case `npm install` and `npm install --dev` should be ran separately.

Comment: Thanks for this great answer, but you say `dependencies are required to run, devDependencies only to develop, e.g.: [...] Coffeescript to Javascript transpilation`, but this is incorrect if your project is an app and is not meant to be distributed as an npm package. In this case, you will need all of your build tools (inc. transpilation) in your `dependencies` section. Personally I think that this distinction is worth mentioning at the top of your answer. Cheers.

Comment: It's important to remark that `devDependencies` aren't installed when `NODE_ENV` is set to `production`.

Comment: https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-uglify/blob/master/package.json the `grant` package is not in peerDependencies, it's in devDependencies

Comment: `dependencies are installed on both:

npm install from a directory that contains package.json
npm install $package on any other directory`

I installed a package from npm. All the dependencies of this package should also automatically get installed in my project, right? But this is not happening. @CiroSantilliOurBigBook.com

Comment: @AbhinandanKushwaha that sounds weird, as without dependencies the package has no ochance of working. Something seems very wrong.

Comment: Yes @CiroSantilliOurBigBook.com I have to manually install the dependencies listed in `package.json` of the library, then the package works.

Comment: *This would not work then if each plugin required a different Grunt version* 0 why?  if npm allows having multiple versions of any package, right? so it does allow it for grunt, right?  user would then have to specify which version of grunt to use (as they would for any other package), and that version would only load compatible plugins.  yes it is a mess but that's the cost of coexistence of multiple versions; i don't see what changes "things being plugins" -- the dep is now more silent, so what?

Comment: `--dev` isn't mentioned in the [v10 npm-install documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v10/commands/npm-install). Does anyone know what happened to it?

Comment: In npm 10:
Use `npm install --save-dev` to save a dependency as a devDependency and `npm install --omit=dev` to skip installing such dependencies for production.

Answer (score 642):

If you do not want to install devDependencies you can use `npm install --production`

Comment: npm install --save is for software dependancy?

Comment: npm install will install all dependencies. --save flag is used when you want to add the specific module to package.json too. ex:- npm install uglify --save will install uglify in your project folder and add uglify to project, package.json file.

Comment: And because we're talking devDependencies, you can use --save-dev to save the new module as a devDependency.  Example: npm install uglify --save-dev

Comment: As of npm 5, the `--save` option is no longer necessary. If you do "npm install my-package", it will add my-package as a dependency in your `package.json` file.

Comment: just npm install

Comment: *As of npm 5, the --save option is no longer necessary*. That's great news! I hadn't realized this before. I always found it annoying that most docs neglect the `--save` option when really it hardly ever makes sense not to save the fact you added a dependency.

Answer (score 165):

**dependencies**
Dependencies that your project needs to run, like a library that provides functions that you call from your code.
They are installed transitively (if A depends on B depends on C, npm install on A will install B and C).
*Example: lodash: your project calls some lodash functions.*

**devDependencies**
Dependencies you only need during development or releasing, like compilers that take your code and compile it into javascript, test frameworks or documentation generators.
They are not installed transitively (if A depends on B dev-depends on C, npm install on A will install B only).
*Example: grunt: your project uses grunt to build itself.*

**peerDependencies**
Dependencies that your project hooks into, or modifies, in the parent project, usually a plugin for some other library or tool. It is just intended to be a check, making sure that the parent project (project that will depend on your project) has a dependency on the project you hook into. So if you make a plugin C that adds functionality to library B, then someone making a project A will need to have a dependency on B if they have a dependency on C.
They are not installed (unless npm < 3), they are only checked for.
*Example: grunt: your project adds functionality to grunt and can only be used on projects that use grunt.*

This documentation explains peer dependencies really well: https://nodejs.org/en/blog/npm/peer-dependencies/

Also, the npm documentation has been improved over time, and now has better explanations of the different types of dependencies: https://github.com/npm/cli/blob/latest/docs/content/configuring-npm/package-json.md#devdependencies

Comment: Should be market as "answer" - clear and neat, first sentence under "peerDependencies" explains everything correctly, without digging into how versions are resolved in npm which is not required to understand what peerDependecies are for.

Comment: Finally an answer to peerDependencies that has satisfied the "why?" instead of "how?". Very helpful!

Answer (score 152):

As an example, mocha would normally be a devDependency, since testing isn't necessary in production, while express would be a dependency.

Comment: I would lean towards putting testing as a dependency since you may want to run self-tests before launching the production server

Comment: I would instead recommend using a continuous integration service like Hudson or CircleCI that runs your tests and then deploys to production if they pass.

Comment: It may still be relevant to test the actual server because the CI server might differ somehow from the prod server, and this difference may e.g. prevent the app from starting up...

Comment: @Nicole why would you make your staging server not identical in configuration to your prod?

Comment: @Lucas e.g. the staging server usually has a different DB and resides in a different network segment than the prod machine. Any of these might be a potential cause for a failure. (Depends on your specific setup and requirements, of course.)

Comment: Then again, adding test dependencies as regular dependencies introduces a whole bunch of extra libraries, each of which may fail in some way. I would lean (pun!) towards light-weight production servers with as little code on them as possible. Remember, the best code is no code!

Answer (score 81):

To save a package to *package.json* as dev dependencies:

```
npm install "$package" --save-dev
```

When you run `npm install` it will install both `devDependencies` and `dependencies`. To avoid install `devDependencies` run:

```
npm install --production
```

Comment: you can also use :
npm i -S

Answer (score 47):

There are some modules and packages only necessary for development, which are not needed in production. Like it says it in the [documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/specifying-dependencies-and-devdependencies-in-a-package-json-file):

> If someone is planning on downloading and using your module in their program, then they probably don't want or need to download and build the external test or documentation framework that you use. In this case, it's best to list these additional items in a devDependencies hash.

Comment: What if you're running only bundle.js file on production? do you really need those dependencies?

Comment: If you are running bundle.js on the server, you are doing server-side webpack or something... Please check if that's the case because it usually isn't and it actually takes a lot of work to get that running correctly (I know because I did that). I suspect your bundle.js is just served up to browsers and contains the client-side code.

Comment: The part that confuses me is, What is production here? is it the CDN server, I deploy my builds on or it the client browser that runs my build ?

Answer (score 30):

`peerDependencies` didn't quite make sense for me until I read this snippet from [a blog post](https://blog.domenic.me/peer-dependencies/) on the topic [Ciro mentioned above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22004559/1028230):

> What [**plugins**] need is a way of expressing these “dependencies” between plugins and their host package. Some way of saying, “I only work when plugged in to version 1.2.x of my host package, so if you install me, be sure that it’s alongside a compatible host.” We call this relationship a peer dependency.

#### The plugin does *expect* a specific version of the host...

`peerDependencies` are for plugins, libraries that require a "host" library to perform their function, but may have been written at a time *before* the latest version of the host was released.

That is, if I write `PluginX v1` for `HostLibraryX v3` and walk away, there's no guarantee `PluginX v1` will work when `HostLibraryX v4` (or even `HostLibraryX v3.0.1`) is released.

#### ... but the plugin doesn't *depend* on the host...

From the point of view of the plugin, it only *adds* functions to the host library. I don't really "need" the host to add a dependency to a plugin, and plugins often don't literally *depend* on their host. If you don't have the host, the plugin harmlessly does nothing.

**This means `dependencies` isn't really the right concept for plugins.**

Even worse, if my host was treated like a dependency, we'd end up in this situation that [the same blog post mentions](https://blog.domenic.me/peer-dependencies/#the-problem-plugins) (edited a little to use this answer's made up host & plugin):

> But now, [if we treat the contemporary version of HostLibraryX as a dependency for PluginX,] running `npm install` results in the unexpected dependency graph of
>
> ```
> ├── HostLibraryX@4.0.0
> └─┬ PluginX@1.0.0
>   └── HostLibraryX@3.0.0
> ```
>
> I’ll leave the subtle failures that come from the plugin using a different [HostLibraryX] API than the main application to your imagination.

#### ... and the host obviously doesn't depend on the plugin...

... that's the whole point of plugins. Now if the host was nice enough to include dependency information for *all* of its plugins, that'd solve the problem, but *that'd also introduce a huge new cultural problem*: plugin management!

The whole point of plugins is that they can pair up anonymously. In a perfect world, having the host manage 'em all would be neat & tidy, but we're not going to require libraries herd cats.

#### If we're not hierarchically dependent, maybe we're intradependent peers...

Instead, we have the concept of being peers. Neither host nor plugin sits in the other's dependency bucket. Both live at the same level of the dependency graph.

---

### ... but this is not an automatable relationship. *<<< Moneyball!!!*

If I'm `PluginX v1` and *expect* a peer of (that is, *have a peerDependency of*) `HostLibraryX v3`, I'll say so. If you've auto-upgraded to the latest `HostLibraryX v4` (note that's version ***4***) *AND* have `Plugin v1` installed, you need to know, right?

*`npm` can't manage this situation for me --*

> "Hey, I see you're using `PluginX v1`! I'm automatically downgrading `HostLibraryX` from v4 to v3, kk?"

... or...

> "Hey I see you're using `PluginX v1`. That expects `HostLibraryX v3`, which you've left in the dust during your last update. To be safe, I'm automatically uninstalling `Plugin v1`*!!1!*

How about no, npm?!

So npm doesn't. It alerts you to the situation, and lets you figure out if `HostLibraryX v4` is a suitable peer for `Plugin v1`.

---

#### Coda

Good `peerDependency` management in plugins will make this concept work more intuitively in practice. From [the blog post](https://blog.domenic.me/peer-dependencies/#using-peer-dependencies), yet again...

> One piece of advice: peer dependency requirements, unlike those for regular dependencies, should be lenient. You should not lock your peer dependencies down to specific patch versions. It would be really annoying if one Chai plugin peer-depended on Chai 1.4.1, while another depended on Chai 1.5.0, simply because the authors were lazy and didn’t spend the time figuring out the actual minimum version of Chai they are compatible with.

Comment: I still don't get the argument that the plugin does not *depend* but *expects* the host package -- what is the difference, really?   If it's just that the plugin does not require/import the host lib then that seems like a technicality, one could still say the plugin depends on it, clearly it still depends on (by implementing) the *interface* defined by it.

Comment: @AloisMahdal You're using human logic & definitions for those words, but we have to be specialized here. If libDependsV2 _depends_ on libRequirement V3, in npm-land, libRequirementV3 **will be installed if libDependsV2 is in package.json**. We _don't_ want that with plugins. Key is this quote: "_If you don't have the host, the plugin harmlessly does nothing._" If the plugin didn't "fail gracefully", we would have an issue. But the plugin expects a peer relationship and "comes alive" if [and only if] a compatible host is found. Otherwise you end up with the management issues I describe, above.

Comment: Look back over the **... but the plugin doesn't depend on the host...** section. It's a fine (_qua_ "small") distinction, and you could write a "plugin" that used conventional dependencies if you wanted, but that tight coupling is what `peerDependencies` tries to work around. That is, your scenario is already handled, but what can we do if we _don't_ want to use tightly coupled dependencies? We'd get a lot more flexibility, but npm could no longer automate the enforcement of that relationship. If that works for what you'd like to accomplish, `peerDependencies` lets you do it.

Comment: Finally, the blog makes a good point here: "_One piece of advice: peer dependency requirements, unlike those for regular dependencies, should be lenient._" What `peerDependencies` does for you is allow an "out of spec" plugin to stick around even when libRequirementV4 is released. If it libDependsV2 automagically works with the new version, perfect! But since we've told npm, "this isn't a relationship for you to enforce", npm can only "_alert you to the situation, and let you figure out if `HostLibraryX v4` is a suitable peer for `Plugin v1`._"

Answer (score 25):

A simple explanation that made it more clear to me is:

When you deploy your app, modules in dependencies need to be installed or your app won't work. Modules in devDependencies don't need to be installed on the production server since you're not developing on that machine.
[link](https://www.reddit.com/r/node/comments/1nticr/whats_the_difference_between_dependencies_and/)

Comment: So, if we are making website and in prod version all libs will be inlined into `vendor.js`, all our deps should be dev deps if compiled code is commited into the repo? And it should be commited, as otherwice it's strange that you have to compile module, not just install it (and testing is also somewhere here as any change in submodules can lead to regression)...

Comment: Awesome answer, but there is a question? Does possible  Webpack build a corrupted bundle? My guess is devDependencies packages will not work in product version, `webpack -p` I mean. please answer my question.

Comment: If there is any issue while production build, your deployment process should be designed in a way that it shows error at build time and does not push corrupted code to production(e.g. you can try Jenkins). Devdependencies anyways are not required to be installed on production server.

Answer (score 24):

I found a simple explanation.

Short Answer:

**dependencies**
"...are those that your project really needs to be able to work in production."

**devDependencies**
"...are those that you need during development."

**peerDependencies**
"if you want to create and publish your own library so that it can be used as a dependency"

More details in this post:
https://code-trotter.com/web/dependencies-vs-devdependencies-vs-peerdependencies

Comment: Top answer are pretty descriptive and detailed but this answer ELI5'd `peerDependencies` for me.

Answer (score 20):

I'd like to add to the answer my view on these dependencies explanations

- `dependencies` are used for direct usage in your codebase, things that usually end up in the production code, or chunks of code
- `devDependencies` are used for the build process, tools that help you manage how the end code will end up, third party test modules, (ex. webpack stuff)

Comment: What about css assets?

Answer (score 11):

In short

1. **Dependencies** -  `npm install <package> --save-prod` installs packages required by your application in production environment.
2. **DevDependencies** -  `npm install <package> --save-dev` installs
       packages required only for local development and testing
3. Just typing `npm install` installs all packages mentioned in the
   package.json

so if you are working on your local computer just type `npm install` and continue :)

Answer (score 6):

**dependencies**: packages that your project/package needs to work in production.

**devDependencies**: packages that your project/package needs to work while development but are not needed on production (eg: testing packages)

**peerDependencies**: packages that your project/package needs to work in tandem with (“colaborating” with them) or as a base, **useful mainly when you are developing a plugin/component** to let know with which version of the “main” package your plugin/component is supposed to work with (eg: React 16)

Answer (score 4):

## Dependencies

These are the packages that your package needs to run, so they will be installed when people run

```
 npm install PACKAGE-NAME
```

An example would be if you used jQuery in your project. If someone doesn't have jQuery installed, then it wouldn't work. To save as a dependency, use

```
 npm install --save
```

## Dev-Dependencies

These are the dependencies that you use in development, but isn't needed when people are using it, so when people run `npm install`, it won't install them since the are not necessary. For example, if you use `mocha` to test, people don't need `mocha` to run, so `npm install` doesn't install it. To save as a dev dependency, use

```
npm install PACKAGE --save-dev
```

## Peer Dependencies

These can be used if you want to create and publish your own library so that it can be used as a dependency. For example, if you want your package to be used as a dependency in another project, then these will also be installed when someone installs the project which has your project as a dependency. Most of the time you won't use peer dependencies.

Answer (score 3):

When trying to distribute an npm package you should avoid using `dependencies`. Instead you need to consider adding it into `peerDependencies`.

#### Update

Most of the time dependencies are just a bunch of libraries that describes your ecosystem. Unless, you're really using a specific version of a library you should instead let the user choose whether or not to install that library and which version to choose by adding it into the peerDependencies.

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it - why **exactly** should using the `dependencies` be avoided?

Comment: Most of the time dependencies are just a bunch of libraries that describes the ecosystem. Unless, you're really using a specific version of a library you should let the user choose whether or not to install that library and which version to choose by adding it into the peerDependencies instead.

Comment: Please add all clarification **to your answer** by editing it

Comment: @NicoHaase Let me know if you have any questions

Answer (score 2):

When using Webpack to bundle a frontend application, the distinction between dependencies and devDependencies is not so clear. For the final bundle, it doesn't matter where you place the dependencies (but it may be important for other tools). That's why the documentation seems confusing.

I found the explanation here: [Do "dependencies" and "devDependencies" matter when using Webpack?](https://jsramblings.com/do-dependencies-devdependencies-matter-when-using-webpack/)

Answer (score 0):

dependencies are required to run, devDependencies only to develop

Comment: An answer which basically proposes the same solution as an existing answer can theoretically still be a valuable contribution, if it explains more, or from a different angle, or more understandably... But this post does not. Please do not expect users to find this post helpful.