# NPM does not publish dependencies

Tags: json, node.js, npm, command-line-interface

I have been fooling around with Node and npm Packages as CLI applications. I have a project with a package.json, all filled in correctly. When I run the application with different arguments via WebStorm, it all works fine. If I publish the npm package however... there are no dependencies... the npm site can't find one.. and when I install the CLI application, it fails running because yeah... the dependencies aren't pulled in...

This is my package.json

```
 {
  "name": "wmg",
  "version": "0.0.8",
  "description": "A Commandline Foolin around",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://github.com/Arvraepe/wmg.git"
  },
  "keywords": ["Stuff", "Foolin"],
  "target": "main",
  "preferGlobal": true,
  "bin": {
    "wmg": "wmg.js"
  },
  "author": "Arne Van Raepenbusch <arvraepe@gmail.com>",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "prompt": "^0.2.14",
    "restify": "^3.0.3",
    "underscore": "^1.8.3"
  }
}
```

I tried running pakmanager deps, but that gave me this strange error

```
======================= WARNING =======================
Assuming browser mode by default is deprecated.
  Include browserDependencies in your package.json
  -- OR --
  pakmanager -e browser build

In the next release of pakmanager, the node environment will be assumed as default
=======================================================


Targeted Environment: browser
[[[deps]]]
[ERROR] The following packages are `require`d, but not in the package, nor on npm:
  wmg
pakmanager {}


======================= WARNING =======================
Assuming browser mode by default is deprecated.
  Include browserDependencies in your package.json
  -- OR --
  pakmanager -e browser build

In the next release of pakmanager, the node environment will be assumed as default
=======================================================
```

Surely my package isn't supposed to be dependent on itself?

Can someone shed some more light on this?

Comment: SUGGESTIONS: 1) Divide and conquer: Try a different, *minimal* package.json to see if you can isolate the problem.  2) Look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22343224/difference-between-tilde-and-caret-in-package-json) for possible issues with version syntax.  3) Look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18875674/whats-the-difference-between-dependencies-devdependencies-and-peerdependencies) for possible issues with "dependencies" vs. "devDependencies".  Good luck - and please post back what you find!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I looked at your package, and as others have noted you have `devDependencies` listed but no `dependencies`.   Typically `devDependencies` is for things like test frameworks, which you need to work on the package but not to use it.  Both `prompt` and `restify` are used in your app and should be listed in a `dependencies` object instead of `devDependencies`.

Comment: This is probably because I have used NPM install prompt --save-dev for example... ? When I looked at node packages they all put --save-dev at the end to save it in your package file... I thought this was good enough. What you are saying makes perfect sense though.

Comment: @Arninja: For actual dependencies use --save instead of --save-dev

Comment: I figured it out now. It's so obvious that it's becoming embarrassing ;-) but all that ends well is well. Thanks for all the help, info and tips!

Comment: My package.json has "dependencies" not "devDependencies" and i am getting this exact error :/

Answer (score 1):

Your package.json file contains no dependencies. Only devDependencies which npm assumes are required only for development (mocha for example) and are not required for installation.

If any of your devDependencies are actual user dependencies move them to dependencies.

Comment: You are right! I could not however set two answers as fixed... thank you for your time!