# Install webpack to separate dependencies?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, dependencies, webpack

Im going through a tutorial on webpack (third day and still confused as anything!) and Im combing through the commands:

```
npm i webpack --save-dev
```

The above command installs the webpack as a node module to '--save-dev'? Im confused what '--save-dev' is. And is it a normal convention for webpacks to use?

Also where is this dependency being saved? I dont find any reference to it in `webpack.config.js` or `package.json` for that matter?

Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`npm i webpack --save-dev` is a shorthand for `npm install webpack --save-dev`. The `--save-dev` flag tells `npm` to save the dependency as a *development dependency*, i.e. it will be listed in `devDependencies` in `package.json` instead of the "normal" `dependencies` section.

What this means is that development dependencies are dependencies that are *not required to run* your application, but only for development purposes like running unit tests, bundling the application, etc. etc.

From the [documentation for *npm install*](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install):

> -D, --save-dev: Package will appear in your devDependencies.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18875674/whats-the-difference-between-dependencies-devdependencies-and-peerdependencies) is another stackoverflow post on differences between "normal" dependencies and development dependencies.

Cheers, Alex