# How to handle npm3 peer dependency conflict

Tags: node.js, meteor, reactjs, npm, fixed-data-table

I just migrate my meteor project to 1.3 following this [guide](https://guide.meteor.com/1.3-migration.html) and they suggest me to use npm react package instead of atmosphere one.

When I install react and react-dom I get latest version which is 15.0.1

However, my project is using npm's [fixed-data-table](https://github.com/facebook/fixed-data-table) which have peer dependency of

```
  "peerDependencies": {
    "react": ">=0.13.0 <0.15.0 || ^0.14.0-beta3",
    "react-dom": ">=0.14.0 <0.15.0 || ^0.14.0-beta3"
  }
```

So if I use react 15.0.1 I will run into unmet peer dependency error.

How to handle such case? or does it mean I cannot use fixed-data-table if I'm using react 15?

I cannot install older version of react as there are other packages that have `react@^15.0.1` as peer dependency as well.

Answer (score 1):

What's the `npm` version are you using?
I solved this problem after upgrade npm to 3.x. The rule `npm treat peerDependencies has changed between`npm` 3.x and 2.x, please refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18875674/whats-the-difference-between-dependencies-devdependencies-and-peerdependencies)

Although fixed-data-table's peerDependencies declared that it needs react < 0.15.0, but fixed-data-table functions well under react 15.0, so just ignore this WARN.