# How does npm know you're in dev/developing mode?

Tags: npm

Can someone explain to me what it means to --save-dev and how this impacts distribution and how NPM is aware of what you're trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First**, see the answer to this question, [What's the difference between dependencies, devDependencies and peerDependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18875674/whats-the-difference-between-dependencies-devdependencies-and-peerdependencies).

That will explain a TON.

**Second**, npm will install devDependencies by default unless one of two things is true, in which case devDependencies will be skipped.  These things are:

1. You explicitly tell npm it's production with `npm install --production`
2. You set an environment variable that npm checks, `NODE_ENVIRONMENT=production`

In general, if you are distributing to something like Heroku, they will have the production flag set and your devDependencies will **not** be installed.  So only install things with the `--save-dev` or `-D` flag (both do the same thing) if it is a module used for development, such as tests/mocks/scaffolding/etc.

Comment: npm also checks for the `NODE_ENV` environment variable

Answer (score 1):

`--save-dev` is useful for dependencies such as unit testing libraries.  These dependencies are not required by the application to run in production; therefore if you published your package, consumers of your package would not get these dev dependencies in their node_modules folder.

NPM doesn't necessarily know that your in dev mode, it's just a package manager that allows you to install packages into your working directory and publish your own package from said directory.

Comment: What does it mean for an application being "run" in production, how does npm know you're running in production or development?

Comment: Matthew Bakaitis's answer gave a good description of how npm knows not to install dev dependencies.  You either install with the production flag `--production` or you set the environment variable, NODE_ENVIRONMENT, to "production"