# Dev dependencies vs dependencies in node.js

Tags: node.js, npm

In a node project I found 2 kind of dependencies:

```
    "dependencies": {
        "axios": "0.9.1",
        "express": "4.13.4",
        "lodash": "4.6.1",
        "react": "^0.14.7",
        "react-dom": "^0.14.7",
        "react-redux": "^4.4.0",
        "react-router": "^2.0.0",
        "redux": "^3.3.1"
      },
      "devDependencies": {
        "babel-core": "^6.5.2"
}
```

I know the author install it via `npm install babel-core --save -dev`

but what is that for? when you push your code, the `devDependencies` module is still there.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the difference between dependencies, devDependencies and peerDependencies in npm package.json file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18875674/whats-the-difference-between-dependencies-devdependencies-and-peerdependencies)

Comment: when you search on google , the first result will answer your question.

Comment: Best Link to be referred for the difference is - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18875674/whats-the-difference-between-dependencies-devdependencies-and-peerdependencies]

Answer (score 17):

I wrote an article about this however it was taken down.

Snippets from the article:

```
mod-a
  dev-dependents:
    - mod-b
  dependents:
    - mod-c

mod-d
﻿  dev-dependents:
    - mod-e
  dependents:
    - mod-a

----

npm install mod-d

installed modules:
  - mod-d
  - mod-a
  - mod-c

----

checkout the mod-d code repository

npm install

installed modules:
  - mod-a
  - mod-c
  - mod-e
```

### Publishing to npm

If you are publishing to npm, then it is important that you use the correct flag for the correct modules. If it is something that your npm module needs to function, then use the "--save" flag to save the module as a dependency. If it is something that your module doesn't need to function but it is needed for testing, then use the "--save-dev" flag.

```
# For dependent modules
﻿npm install dependent-module --save

﻿# For dev-dependent modules
np﻿m install development-module --save-dev
```

### Not for npm

If you aren't publishing to npm, it technically doesn't matter which flag you use. However, I find it a good practice to use the "--save" flag for modules that introduce non-standard code into the source files. Then use the "--sav-dev" flag for modules that are required for your compiler to function.

```
# For modules that introduce non-standard source code
npm install source-module --save

﻿# For modules that your compiler needs to function
np﻿m install compiler-module --save-dev
```

Comment: Yes I wrote the aritcle :P

Comment: Yes both of the explanation helps me alot.

Comment: Ok I figured out why the link stopped working. I only have a free account on LinkedIn and apparently free accounts seem to have an article view limit. I'm currently finding a new home for it. I will update the answer when it is available to be read at its new home.

Comment: An update on what's happening with the article. I tried getting it published, I had interest from publishers but needed to add more details to it about more things if they were going to publish it. I haven't finished updating the article yet with the changes they requested (I've been procrastinating a bit). I also need to update it since the npm website has changed styling recently.

Comment: FYI, I never republished the article. The answer here gets across what I want to say sufficiently enough I think.

Answer (score 13):

Dependencies vs dev dependencies

Dev dependencies are modules which are only required during development whereas dependencies are required at runtime.
If you are deploying your application, dependencies has to be installed, or else your app simply will not work. Libraries that you call from your code that enables the program to run can be considered as adependencies.

Eg- React , React - dom

Dev dependency modules need not be installed in the production server since you are not gonna develop in that machine .compilers that covert your code to javascript , test frameworks and document generators can be considered as dev-dependencies since they are only required during development .

Eg- ESLint , Babel , webpack

Answer (score 5):

Main difference between the two is:

-in devdependencies, developer customize or modify the node package according to the requirement. For example while making grunt task we change the task as per requirement in Gruntfile, same as case with babel you are using.

-in dependencies, developer directly use the node package without the change ex-express.

Hopefully it clears your doubt.