# how to upgrade a dependency of a global package in npm

Tags: node.js, npm, versioning

I have installed globally `pouchdb-server` and I got this message about `graceful-fs`:

```
$ npm install -g pouchdb-server
npm WARN deprecated minimatch@0.2.14: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
npm WARN deprecated graceful-fs@1.2.3: graceful-fs v3.0.0 and before will fail on node releases >= v7.0. Please update to graceful-fs@^4.0.0 as soon as possible. Use 'npm ls graceful-fs' to find it in the tree.
```

As the message says, the package will failwith `node > 7.0` (which I use), so I would like to know how to perform the upgrade.

If I execute:

```
$ npm ls graceful-fs -g
```

I see that `graceful-fs` is used in several global packages, but the only one with the old version is in `pouchdb-server:

```
├─┬ pouchdb-server@1.2.1
│ ├─┬ couchdb-harness@0.1.6
│ │ └─┬ glob@3.1.21
│ │   └── graceful-fs@1.2.3
│ ├─┬ http-pouchdb@1.1.3
│ │ └─┬ pouchdb@5.4.5
│ │   └─┬ lie@3.0.4
│ │     └─┬ es3ify@0.2.2
│ │       └─┬ jstransform@11.0.3
│ │         └─┬ commoner@0.10.8
│ │           └── graceful-fs@4.1.11
│ ├─┬ pouchdb-adapter-node-websql@6.1.0
│ │ └─┬ websql@0.4.4
│ │   └─┬ sqlite3@3.1.8
│ │     └─┬ node-pre-gyp@0.6.31
│ │       ├─┬ tar@2.2.1
│ │       │ └─┬ fstream@1.0.10
│ │       │   └── graceful-fs@4.1.9
│ │       └─┬ tar-pack@3.3.0
│ │         └─┬ fstream@1.0.10
│ │           └── graceful-fs@4.1.9
│ └─┬ pouchdb-node@6.1.0
│   └─┬ leveldown@1.5.0
│     └─┬ prebuild@4.5.0
│       ├─┬ node-gyp@3.4.0
│       │ ├─┬ fstream@1.0.10
│       │ │ └── graceful-fs@4.1.11
│       │ └── graceful-fs@4.1.11
│       └─┬ node-ninja@1.0.2
│         └── graceful-fs@4.1.11
├─┬ webpack@1.13.1
│ ├─┬ enhanced-resolve@0.9.1
│ │ └── graceful-fs@4.1.4
│ └─┬ watchpack@0.2.9
│   └─┬ chokidar@1.5.1
│     └─┬ fsevents@1.0.12
│       └─┬ node-pre-gyp@0.6.25
│         └─┬ tar@2.2.1
│           └─┬ fstream@1.0.8
│             └── graceful-fs@4.1.3
```

I've tried `npm update -g graceful-fs` but this doesn't work, what is the proper way to uppgrade a package that is a dependency of a global package?

Just to be clear: I don't want to globally install the `graceful-fs` package;  rather, I want to upgrade the installation of `graceful-fs` that is used by the `pouchdb-server` package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You *cannot fix this yourself*, you need to *ask the package maintainer(s) to upgrade their dependencies*.**

The best *you* can do is to run `npm update -g` (a.k.a. `npm upgrade -g`) to ensure that all (global, in this case) packages are upgraded to the latest version of their dependencies as allowed by their dependency specs. in their respective `package.json` files.

Beyond that, upgrading to *higher* version numbers among the dependencies cannot be done, unless the package(s) in question are *themselves* modified to depend (allow depending) on more recent versions of their dependent packages.

Package designers specify a permissible *range* of version numbers among dependent packages, and going outside that range is usually not safe due to the rules of [semver (semantic versioning)](http://semver.org/).
Unfortunately, that means that packages that haven't had their dependencies updated in a long time run the risk of being obsoleted by changes in Node.js/npm.

---

Looking at **your specific case**:

`pouchdb-server` has a dependency on `"couchdb-harness": "*"`, which specifies that that *any* `couchdb-harness` version satisfies the dependency (which is unusually permissive, possibly at the expense of robustness).

**`couchdb-harness` is the problem**, however: it depends on `"glob": "~3.1.21"`, which means that it **won't install and work with `glob` package versions higher than `3.1.x`** - see [npm's docs on semver version specifications](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/semver).

(The latest `glob` `3.x` package itself depends on `"minimatch": "~0.2.11"`, which explains the other warning, which, however, will go away if `couchdb-harness` updates its dependencies to the *latest* `glob` version.)

Comment: Thank you for a great and thorough explanation of what is going on! I've just opened an issue in couchdb-harness repository to ask them to upgrade the dependencies

Answer (score 0):

Got this from [here](https://github.com/jshint/jshint/issues/2952),

```
$ npm update minimatch
$ npm -v minimatch
2.10.1
$ npm install -g npm@3
/usr/local/bin/npm -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js
npm@3.10.5 /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm
$ npm install -g minimatch@3.0.2
/usr/local/lib
└─┬ minimatch@3.0.2 
  └─┬ brace-expansion@1.1.6 
    ├── balanced-match@0.4.2 
    └── concat-map@0.0.1 

$ npm -v minimatch
3.10.5
```

For graceful-fs try:

```
npm install -g graceful-fs graceful-fs@latest
```

Comment: I've edited my question to clarify what I want ... I don't want to install graceful-fs as a global package, I want to upgrade the installation of the package made by pouchdb-server

Answer (score 0):

Is there a particular reason why you need to install `pouchdb-server` globally?

Look into adding it to your `packages.json` under `peerDependencies`, uninstalling it globally, removing your local node_modules folder, then install from scratch.

It's typically recommended against installing globally—it's preferable to install packages via `devDependencies`, `peerDependencies`, etc.

This is preferable as it avoids side effects of other packages using the same dependencies. Also, you're able keep all dependencies in version control.

### References

[What's the difference between dependencies, devDependencies and peerDependencies in npm package.json file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18875674/whats-the-difference-between-dependencies-devdependencies-and-peerdependencies#22004559)