# Firebase deploy functions with Sharp library fails in Google Cloud Build

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-build, sharp

After migrating to Google Cloud Build from Bitbucket Pipelines the Firebase deployment is failing. The setup was deploying successfully both on Bitbucket Pipelines and locally.

No further explanation is given other than error below. I have comment parts of the code to to realize that "const sharp = require('sharp')" was one command that was making the build to fail.

But there is no apparent reason why "firebase deploy" fails with "require('sharp')" and I have to way to tackle this.

Firebase deploy output in Google Cloud Build

```
Step #5: === Deploying to 'werkout-staging-b1483'...
Step #5: 
Step #5: i  deploying functions
Step #5: ✔  functions: Finished running predeploy script.
Step #5: i  functions: ensuring necessary APIs are enabled...
Step #5: ✔  functions: all necessary APIs are enabled
Step #5: i  functions: preparing functions/cloud_functions directory for uploading...
Step #5: 
Step #5: Error: There was an unknown problem while trying to parse function triggers. Please ensure you are using Node.js v6 or greater.
Finished Step #5
ERROR
ERROR: build step 5 "gcr.io/werkout-staging-b1483/firebase" failed: exit status 2
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM cypress/base:10.15.3

#CMD ["node"]

RUN npm install -g firebase-tools@^7.0.0
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/local/bin/firebase"]
```

Any ideas?

Comment: maybe duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44990782/firebase-functions-deploy-error

Comment: I have read that question. My error is much less verbose and happens only on Cloud Build. Also I know it's not a problem with Node version as I used the same docker image on Bitbucket Pipelines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figure it out for real this time.

I ran npm ci to build the cloud functions and them firebase deploy to deploy them to the cloud. The problem was that as you see in the docker file above gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/firebase image was build with node 10.15.3 while the gcr.io/cloud-builders/npm was using node 8. The only npm packages that was picky enough was Sharp and so it failed to build.

Worst of all is that firebase was very secretive about this and I have no lead to tackle over than pure speculation.

```
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/npm'
  args: [ 'run', 'build' ]

- name: 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/firebase'
  args: [ 'firebase', 'deploy' ]
```

The solution:

```
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/npm:node-10.10.0'
  args: [ 'run', 'build' ]

- name: 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/firebase'
  args: [ 'firebase', 'deploy' ]
```

And this should match the version of the node engine specified in cloud functions package.json.

Comment: setting node: "10" in package json as stated here https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/manage-functions#set_nodejs_version and really using node 10 works

Comment: Where do you set the data mentioned in "The solution" part?

Comment: It’s the cloud build yaml file

Comment: where's the cloud build yaml file located?