# How to fix Npm missing peer dependency

Tags: npm, npm-install, npm-update

I do not know how to fix below peer dependency error.

```
mondwan@mondwan-All-Series:~/Documents/git/py-cli_build_tools$ sudo npm -g list | grep eslint    
├─┬ babel-eslint@7.1.1
├─┬ eslint@3.12.2
├─┬ eslint-config-airbnb@13.0.0
│ └── eslint-config-airbnb-base@10.0.1
├─┬ eslint-config-eslint@3.0.0
├─┬ eslint-plugin-import@2.2.0
│ ├─┬ eslint-import-resolver-node@0.2.3
│ ├─┬ eslint-module-utils@2.0.0
├─┬ UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y@3.0.2
├─┬ eslint-plugin-react@6.8.0
npm ERR! peer dep missing: eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y@^2.2.3, required by eslint-config-airbnb@13.0.0
```

As you see, I have installed `eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y@3.0.2` which is definitely fulfill `^2.2.3` required by

`eslint-config-airbnb`. However, it shows such error message. Any idea for solving such problem?

Comment: Is this the whole log? Some times I have to run `npm install` with `--no-bin-links`, but this just occurs on Windows. the npm call is just like that `npm install <module> --no-bin-links` . I hope it helps

Comment: Thanks. It is not a full log as they are too long. And I got the answer below. It turns out that I misunderstood the caret symbol.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I have mis-understood the meaning of the `^` in version `^2.2.3`.

After reading [this link](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/semver#caret-ranges-123-025-004), `^2.2.3` means `>=2.2.3 <3.X`. That's why npm throws an warning.

Besides, below are links about `peer-dependencies`

- [What's the difference between dependencies, devDependencies and peerDependencies in npm package.json file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18875674/whats-the-difference-between-dependencies-devdependencies-and-peerdependencies)
- https://nodejs.org/en/blog/npm/peer-dependencies/