# How to determine if npm module installed in bash

Tags: bash, npm

My objective is to only install this npm package if it's not already available.  This continues to to execute even when I've installed the module globally.

```
if [ npm list -g widdershins &> /dev/null ] || [ ! -d node_modules ]; then
    npm install widdershins --no-shrinkwrap
fi
```

How can I adjust this to detect when it's installed globally?

Comment: The first clause has an exit status of 0 ("true") if the module is already installed, isn't that the opposite of what you want?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

if you want a one liner:

Local

```
npm list | grep widdershins || npm install widdershins --no-shrinkwrap
```

Global:

```
npm list -g | grep widdershins || npm install -g widdershins --no-shrinkwrap
```

Answer (score 12):

```
package='widdershins'
if [ `npm list -g | grep -c $package` -eq 0 ]; then
    npm install $package --no-shrinkwrap
fi
```

alternative including the directory check:

```
package='widdershins'
if [ `npm list -g | grep -c $package` -eq 0 -o ! -d node_module ]; then
    npm install $package --no-shrinkwrap
fi
```

Explaination:

- `npm list -g` lists all installed packages
- `grep -c $package` prints a count of lines containing $package (which is substituted to 'widdershins' in our case)
- `-eq` is an equals check, e.g. `$a -eq $b` returns true if $a is equal to $b, and false otherwise.
- `-d` checks if the given argument is a directory (returns true if it is)
- `!` is the negation operator, in our case is negates the -d result
- `-o` is the logical or operator

To sum it up:

- First code: if the $package is installed, then the -eq result is false and this causes the if statement to be false. If $package is not installed, then the -eq result is true (and the if statement is also true).
- Second code: in addition to description of first code, if node_module is a directory, then the if statement is false. If node_module is not a directory then the if statement is true. And this is independend from the -eq result because of the logical or connection.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17937960/how-to-list-npm-user-installed-packages) could also help you.

Comment: This doesn't seem to quite work.  `widdershins@3.4.0` is in the output of `npm list -g` but it's still trying to install

Comment: What does `-eq 0 -o` do?

Comment: `-eq` is an equals check. It returns true if the left operator is equal to the right operator. `grep -c $package` counts all lines containing $package (in this case all lines containing the string 'widdershins', and this is also true for 'widdershins@3.4.0'). This means: if the package widdershins is installed, then ``npm list -g | grep -c $package`` returns 1, and this is not equal to 0 (1 -eq 0 is false). The `-o` is the logical `or` operator. It connects the -eq result with the directory check result (`! -d node_module`, which is true, if node_modules is not a directory). Hope this helps.

Comment: I think what's messing this up is that it's putting this on line 1, `npm ERR! peer dep missing: mkdirp@>=0.5.0, required by mkdirp-promise@1.1.0` then the count actually shows up on line 2

Comment: Ok, if i understand this correctly, then i think you have another problem: a problem based on a missing dependency. Maybe on this post you'll find help with this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41275301/how-to-fix-npm-missing-peer-dependency

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
package_name='widdershins'
if [[ "$(npm list -g $package_name)" =~ "empty" ]]; then
    echo "Installing $package_name ..."
    npm install -g $package_name
else
    echo "$package_name is already installed"
fi
```

`npm list -g package-name` returns empty when is not installed, so with that condition you can check if it contains the string empty