# Getting these WARN despite having the superior version of React

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm-install

While attempting some tests with `@testing-library-react` I tried to -unsuccesfully- install  `msw` I noticed these `npm WARN`:

```
npm WARN airbnb-prop-types@2.16.0 requires a peer of react@^0.14 || ^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0-alpha but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN enzyme-adapter-react-16@1.15.6 requires a peer of react@^16.0.0-0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN enzyme-adapter-react-16@1.15.6 requires a peer of react-dom@^16.0.0-0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN react-test-renderer@16.14.0 requires a peer of react@^16.14.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN enzyme-adapter-utils@1.14.0 requires a peer of react@0.13.x || 0.14.x || ^15.0.0-0 || ^16.0.0-0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
```

following to `npm ERR!`

```
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall rename
npm ERR! path C:\xampp\htdocs\react\React-Laravel\vinos-gdl\node_modules\@open-draft\until
npm ERR! dest C:\xampp\htdocs\react\React-Laravel\vinos-gdl\node_modules\@open-draft\.until.DELETE
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'C:\xampp\htdocs\react\React-Laravel\vinos-gdl\node_modules\@open-draft\until' -> 'C:\xampp\htdocs\react\React-Laravel\vinos-gdl\node_modules\@open-draft\.until.DELETE'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
```

I don't understand what im getting required a peer of react when my current `react` and `react-dom` version is `17.0.2`. So I'm not quite sure how to fix those `WARN` which apparently are not letting me to install related packages.

I've already tried deleting `node_modules`, `package.json.lock`, running `npm cache clean` and `npm i` with not much luck.

If I `npm list` I'd get at the end the same:

```
npm ERR! peer dep missing: react@^16.0.0-0, required by enzyme-adapter-react-16@1.15.6
npm ERR! peer dep missing: react-dom@^16.0.0-0, required by enzyme-adapter-react-16@1.15.6
npm ERR! peer dep missing: react@^16.14.0, required by react-test-renderer@16.14.0
npm ERR! peer dep missing: react@0.13.x || 0.14.x || ^15.0.0-0 || ^16.0.0-0, required by enzyme-adapter-utils@1.14.0
npm ERR! peer dep missing: react@^0.14 || ^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0-alpha, required by airbnb-prop-types@2.16.0
```

Package.json:

```
{
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "npm run development",
        "development": "mix",
        "watch": "mix watch",
        "watch-poll": "mix watch -- --watch-options-poll=1000",
        "hot": "mix watch --hot",
        "prod": "npm run production",
        "production": "mix --production",
        "test": "jest --watchAll"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@babel/preset-react": "^7.12.13",
        "@testing-library/jest-dom": "5.11.9",
        "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.5",
        "axios": "^0.21.1",
        "bootstrap": "^4.6.0",
        "jquery": "^3.2",
        "laravel-mix": "^6.0.13",
        "lodash": "^4.17.21",
        "popper.js": "^1.16.1",
        "postcss": "^8.2.8",
        "react": "^17.0.2",
        "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
        "resolve-url-loader": "^3.1.2",
        "sass": "^1.32.8",
        "sass-loader": "^8.0.2"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.13.10",
        "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.35",
        "@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons": "^5.15.3",
        "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.15.3",
        "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "^0.1.14",
        "downshift": "^6.1.1",
        "enzyme": "^3.11.0",
        "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.15.6",
        "enzyme-to-json": "^3.6.1",
        "jest": "^26.6.3",
        "react-bootstrap": "^1.5.0",
        "react-multi-carousel": "^2.6.2",
        "react-paginate": "^7.1.2",
        "react-router": "^5.2.0",
        "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
        "react-select": "^4.3.0",
        "react-test-renderer": "^17.0.2",
        "react-toastify": "^7.0.3"
    },
    "babel": {
        "presets": [
            "@babel/preset-react",
            "@babel/preset-env"
        ],
        "plugins": [
            "@babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx",
            "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime"
        ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, apparently running the last version of `react` andd `react-dom` which is atm `17.0.2` was not the best idea. I rolled back to the `16.14.0` and everything is working fine.

I found here ([How to fix Npm missing peer dependency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41275301/how-to-fix-npm-missing-peer-dependency)) that the `^` is kind of misleading.

ie:

> requires a peer of react@^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0

Meaning that it requires `>15.0.0` but `< 17.0.`