# TypeScript @types/ packages in packages.json

Tags: typescript, npm

I have a silly question regarding the @types dependencies in the package.json file:

In the following URL it is explained that the types should be installed 
as runtime dependency `npm install --save @types/lodash`
[TS 2.x d.ts Consumption](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/consumption.html)

But to me is makes more sense to install the `@types/....` packages 
as dev dependency `npm install --save-dev @types/lodash`

Any thoughts on this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use `--save` when you are developing a module/library and wish to share the `@types` dependencies, otherwise use `--save-dev`.

some context: https://github.com/Microsoft/types-publisher/issues/81

Comment: Additionally, see the comment of jedd.ahyoung to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22004559/3786294) _"This is great! I never realized, but this answer has taught me that the dependencies vs devDependencies difference is only applicable if you're going to publish an npm package. If you're just working on an application or site, it shouldn't matter too much. Thanks! – jedd.ahyoung"_