# Node.js app deploy in heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku

I have the following file structure of my **MEAN** app:

```
root
|---> public
      |----> css
      |----> js
              |----> controller
              |----> app.js
      |----> views
      |----> index.html

|---> app
      |----> server.js
|---> node_modules
|---> bower_components
|---> gulpfile.js
|---> package.json
|---> Procfile
```

In this app, I run `public/index.html` using `gulp`,

**gulpfile.js**:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var browserSync = require('browser-sync');
var server = require('gulp-live-server');

gulp.task('server', function() {
     live = new server('app/server.js');
     live.start();
})
gulp.task('serve', ['server'], function() {
   browserSync.init({
      notify: false,
      port: process.env.PORT || 8080,
      server: {
        baseDir: ['public'],
        routes: {
            '/bower_components': 'bower_components'
        }
      }
   });
    gulp.watch(['public/**/*.*'])
        .on('change', browserSync.reload);
});
```

Then communicate with `app` using `REST API`. This is working in local machine. I have uploaded this project into `heroku`.

My **Procfile**:

```
web: node node_modules/gulp/bin/gulp serve
```

But It shows error. I have the following error into `heroku logs`

`2017-05-21T16:26:57.305350+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=myapp.herokuapp.com request_id=some-request-id fwd="fwd-ip" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https`

`2017-05-21T15:53:50.942664+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Cannot find module '/app/node_modules/gulp/bin/gulp'`

My `package.json` file:

```
 {
    "name": "myapp",
    "scripts": {
       "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
       "start": "gulp serve"
    },
    "repository": {
        "type": "git",
        "url": ""
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "async": "^2.4.0",
        "body-parser": "^1.17.2",
        "express": "^4.15.3",
        "mongoose": "^4.10.0",
        "morgan": "^1.8.1",
        "multer": "^1.3.0",
        "underscore": "^1.8.3"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "browser-sync": "^2.18.11",
        "gulp": "^3.9.1",
        "gulp-live-server": "0.0.30"
    }
}
```

Any suggestion? Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Where is your `package.json` located, and what are its contents?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably have `gulp` defined as a development dependency (under `devDepenenies`) in your `package.json` file. NPM only installs `devDependencies` when `NODE_ENV` is **not** set to `production`.

When you deploy to heroku, `NODE_ENV=production`, so `gulp` is never installed. Hence the error...

`Error: Cannot find module '/app/node_modules/gulp/bin/gulp'`

Just move `gulp` and whatever else is required for building your bundle from `devDependencies` to `dependencies`. You can make npm move it for you with..

```
npm uninstall --save-dev gulp
npm install --save gulp
```

Repeat this for each dev dependency required to build your bundle. Or you can just copy and paste them all yourself.

---

This is a common issue without an ideal solution AFAIK. NPM expects that in production, you will have already pre-built your files. As you would if you were publishing them to NPM. However, in heroku and other push to deploy solutions, this is not the case.

Answer (score 0):

[Charlie Martin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1826354/charlie-martin) is correct about `dev-dependencies` and the `--production` flag (which Heroku passes, correctly). You can see [further explanation in the nodejs docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install#description) for `npm install` and [package.json](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#devdependencies) - this piece of the question [has been elaborated on elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22004559/2378943).

However, I would *strongly recommend* that on deployment you *do not run the serve task* via gulp and instead, define your [npm script](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts) `start` to run [browserSync's CLI](https://browsersync.io/docs/command-line). This way, **you can keep gulp as a dev dependency**.

It would probably look something like this:
**package.json**

```
{
  ... other properties ...
  "scripts": {
    "start": "browser-sync start --port 8080 -s"
  },
  ... other stuff ...
}
```

[Browsersync's documentation](https://browsersync.io/docs/command-line) is pretty good so you should find what you need. I'd fiddle with it locally until `npm start` and `gulp serve` do the same thing, then I'd deploy with heroku to see if it worked.