# How can I run `npm prune` but exclude one package

Tags: npm, continuous-integration

Is there a way to run `npm prune` but a single package that is not in the dependencies?

I know it sounds weird, but there is a legit use-case.

Use case:

1. Inside an abstracted CI/CD flow, I want to `npm install` any new additions to the `package.json`
2. Then `npm prune` should remove any extraneous packages that may have been removed from the `package.json`
3. Then I want to `npm install XXXX` a single dependency that is required only for the CI/CD flow, however subsequent flows should not install this if it is already present, thus on the second execution of the CI/CD flow, this `XXXX` package would be removed via the `npm prune` command. :-(

Comment: A possible workaround for the specific use-case mentioned above is to use the [`npm ci`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/commands/npm-ci) command. Note that this will delete all dependencies so it is a bit slower than the `npm install`.

Answer (score 0):

As of [version 9 of npm](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/commands/npm-prune?v=true), it is still not possible to exclude packages when using `npm prune`.

A possible workaround for this issue is to convert the dependency to a [peer dependency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18875674/whats-the-difference-between-dependencies-devdependencies-and-peerdependencies). But this will depend on your use case.