# requires a peer but none was installed

Tags: npm, package.json

My `package.json` looks like this

```
{
  "name": "hello-world",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "The Hello World",
  "author": "",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "tsc && concurrently \"npm run tsc:w\" \"npm run lite\" ",
    "lite": "lite-server",
    "postinstall": "typings install",
    "tsc": "tsc",
    "tsc:w": "tsc -w",
    "typings": "typings"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "~2.0.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "~2.0.1",
    "@angular/core": "~2.0.1",
    "@angular/http": "~2.0.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~2.0.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~2.0.1",
    "@angular/router": "~3.0.1",
    "@angular/upgrade": "~2.0.1",

    "systemjs": "0.19.39",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.8",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.25",

    "angular-in-memory-web-api": "~0.1.1",
    "bootstrap": "4.0.0-alpha.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^3.0.0",
    "lite-server": "^2.2.2",
    "typescript": "^2.0.3",
    "typings": "^1.4.0"
  }
}
```

When I run `npm i` it runs successfully but I got some warnings.

```
npm WARN angular-in-memory-web-api@0.1.17 requires a peer of rxjs@5.0.0-rc.4 but none was installed.
npm WARN angular-in-memory-web-api@0.1.17 requires a peer of zone.js@^0.7.2 but none was installed.
```

I added these lines to `package.json`

```
"peerDependencies": {
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-rc.4",
    "zone.js": "^0.7.2"
}
```

But when I run `npm i` again I still get this warning

```
npm WARN hello-world@1.0.0 requires a peer of rxjs@5.0.0-rc.4 but none was installed.
npm WARN hello-world@1.0.0 requires a peer of zone.js@^0.7.2 but none was installed.
npm WARN angular-in-memory-web-api@0.1.17 requires a peer of rxjs@5.0.0-rc.4 but none was installed.
npm WARN angular-in-memory-web-api@0.1.17 requires a peer of zone.js@^0.7.2 but none was installed.
```

with additional warning for the main application.
**Why is that and how to get rid from this warning?**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the difference between dependencies, devDependencies and peerDependencies in npm package.json file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18875674/whats-the-difference-between-dependencies-devdependencies-and-peerdependencies)

Comment: In short: you just add them in your project as normal dependencies.

Comment: you mean add them to `dependencies` with corresponding versions? Switching to `zone.js^0.7.2` lead to `ERR` and `unmet peer dependency zone.js@0.7.8`

Comment: The asked peer is for version 0.7.8, not ^0.7.2.

Comment: In my post they required `^0.7.2` - requires a peer of zone.js@^0.7.2 but none was installed - but when I added it started requiring `0.7.8`

Comment: Can you post the latest package.json to your question?

Comment: @E_net4 I decided not to fix this warn as it seems when I change angular version I will have another set of warnings

Comment: Possible duplicate of [npm WARN … requires a peer of … but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46053414/npm-warn-requires-a-peer-of-but-none-is-installed-you-must-install-peer)

Comment: [This answer has good explanation and candidates for solution on the possible duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49188160/1148030)

Comment: [Check out this answer with good explanation of the error message and possible solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49188160/1148030)

Answer (score 2):

TL;DR

**Peer Dependencies** are a special kind of dependencies - they used by packages which do not call them directly, giving the user (you) the control. Hence, you have to install these packages manually.

You do not need to add `peerDependencies` to your `package.json`.

The reason you're seeing these error is, some of your dependencies declare `rxjs@5.0.0-rc.4` and `zone.js@^0.7.2` in their `package.json` as `peerDependencies`. This is why when you've added `peerDependencies` in your `package.json`, you get these warning twice.

To understand more about **Peer Dependencies** I suggest reading these:

1. [Peer Dependencies](https://nodejs.org/es/blog/npm/peer-dependencies/)
2. [What are those PeerDependencies in a NodeJS project?](https://dev.to/btdev/what-are-those-peerdepenedencies-in-a-nodejs-project-51jo)
3. This [great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22004559/7126139)

Answer (score 0):

I delete the `node_modules` folder and run `npm install`. The error would go away.