# Installing material-ui showing warning: $ npm install @material-ui/core npm WARN ajv-keywords@3.2.0 requires a peer of ajv@^6.0.0

Tags: reactjs, npm, material-ui

I am installing material-ui: npm install @material-ui/core (which is [the latest version](https://material-ui.com/getting-started/installation/)) for React. 
I got the latest npm version (npm i -g npm, which is now + npm@6.1.0). 
And I also have tried: npm install --save material-ui.

But it always keeps showing me this:

$ npm install @material-ui/core

npm WARN ajv-keywords@3.2.0 requires a peer of ajv@^6.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

- @material-ui/core@1.2.1
  updated 1 package and audited 14597 packages in 8.235s
  found 0 vulnerabilities.

I don't know if this is a material-ui latest version problem? or it is the latest npm problem? So, how do I proceed to install the material-ui for React?

Comment: now using + npm@6.1.0, But still does not work.

Comment: I just have tried: npm install --save material-ui. But still not working....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to install `ajv@^6.0.0`

> npm install -S ajv@^6.0.0

Edit: to add to this, as [described in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49188160/1676032), it seems that npm removed the automatic installation of peer dependencies on npm 3, but if you'd like that to be taken care of automatically, you can use [npm-install-peers](https://github.com/spatie/npm-install-peers)

Comment: Oh,yes. I just have tried `$ npm i ajv` and it worked! thank you~

Comment: Glad to have helped :)
Don't forget to mark this question as answered if it has solved the problem.