# Why does "npm install" tell me "none is installed You must install peer dependencies yourself:"?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, ionic-framework, npm

I'm trying to get a react/redux/ionic app working.

When I run `npm install` I get errors:

```
>`enter code here`npm install
npm WARN @ionic/react@0.0.5 requires a peer of react-router@^4.3.1 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @ionic/react@0.0.5 requires a peer of react-router-dom@^4.3.1 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
```

But when I look in `package.json` it certainly looks as if `react-router` and `react-router-dom` should be installed:

```
"@ionic/react": "0.0.5",
"react": "^16.8.6",
"react-dom": "^16.8.6",
"react-redux": "^7.0.3",
"react-router": "^5.0.0",
"react-router-dom": "^5.0.0",
"react-scripts": "3.0.1",
"redux": "^4.0.1",
```

Any ideas as to what might be going on?

Comment: you need to resolve peer dependency conflicts, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46053414/npm-warn-requires-a-peer-of-but-none-is-installed-you-must-install-peer/49188160

Comment: Check out this answer.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/49188160/2992745

Comment: Delete your node_modules folder and your package-lock.json file and rerun npm install

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the version supplied by the warning message
you need to uninstall the newer versions and re-install the specifically supplied versions
uninstall:

```
npm uninstall react-router react-router-dom
```

(as a sanity check, look at package.json to confirm removed)
then install specifically needed versions as supplied in warning

```
npm i -S react-router@^4.3.1 react-router-dom@^4.3.1
```

Comment: The message says @ionic/react needs react-router^4.3.1, and the version installed is greater than that.

Comment: right, so the version needs to start with v4 and the installed version being higher, most likely has modifications that break functionality of what is expected of a v4 intall

Answer (score 0):

You can try cleaning the cache and reinstalling:

`npm cache clean -f`

`npm install`

Comment: Why specifically force? How would that help in this case?