# ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project on mac

Tags: php, docker, backend

hi i have problem with docker

i have tried audit fix

ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
npm WARN ajv-keywords@3.4.0 requires a peer of ajv@^6.9.1 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

updated 1 package and audited 24986 packages in 14.252s
found 34 vulnerabilities (19 low, 11 moderate, 4 high)
  run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details

Comment: It simply says that you need the package `ajv` with version higher or equal to `6.9.1`. Try running `npm install ajv@^6.9.1`. The peer-dependency error above is not related to the vulnerabilities warning below. They are separate. `npm audit fix` can only resolve the latter. Possible answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46053414/npm-warn-requires-a-peer-of-but-none-is-installed-you-must-install-peer/49188160

Comment: Possible duplicate of [npm WARN ... requires a peer of ... but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46053414/npm-warn-requires-a-peer-of-but-none-is-installed-you-must-install-peer)