# Material-UI Can't import slider

Tags: node.js, npm, material-ui

`import Slider from '@material-ui/lab/Slider';`

returns an error on build

```
ERROR in ./src/components/StepSlider/StepSlider-view.jsx
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@material-ui/lab/Slider' in 'D:\GIT\...\components\StepSlider'
 @ ./src/components/StepSlider/StepSlider-view.jsx 2:0-45 29:26-32
 @ ./src/components/StepSlider/index.js
 @ ./src/components/plan_option_slider/PlanOptionSlider-view.jsx
 @ ./src/components/plan_option_slider/index.jsx
 @ ./src/features/plans/plans-view.jsx
 @ ./src/features/plans/index.jsx
 @ ./src/App.jsx
 @ ./src/index.jsx
```

Searching this error tells me to install `lab`, I'd already done that, but figured I'd give it another chance:

`npm install @material-ui/lab`

```
npm WARN bootstrap@4.4.1 requires a peer of popper.js@^1.16.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN material-ui-pickers@2.2.4 requires a peer of @material-ui/core@^3.2.0 but none is installed. You must install 
peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN restaurant_project@1.0.0 No description
npm WARN restaurant_project@1.0.0 No repository field.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.11 (node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.11: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

+ @material-ui/lab@4.0.0-alpha.40
updated 1 package and audited 12006 packages in 13.041s
found 0 vulnerabilities
```

I followed this:
[npm WARN ... requires a peer of ... but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46053414/npm-warn-requires-a-peer-of-but-none-is-installed-you-must-install-peer)
(I was pretty sure I had all this installed, but figured I'd follow directions)

`npm install --save-dev popper.js@^1.16.0`

```
npm WARN deprecated popper.js@1.16.0: Popper changed home, find its new releases at @popperjs/core
npm WARN material-ui-pickers@2.2.4 requires a peer of @material-ui/core@^3.2.0 but none is installed. You must install 
peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN restaurant_project@1.0.0 No description
npm WARN restaurant_project@1.0.0 No repository field.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.11 (node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.11: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

+ popper.js@1.16.0
updated 1 package and audited 12007 packages in 15.415s
found 0 vulnerabilities
```

`npm install --save-dev @material-ui/core@^3.2.0`

```
npm WARN @material-ui/icons@4.5.1 requires a peer of @material-ui/core@^4.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @material-ui/lab@4.0.0-alpha.40 requires a peer of @material-ui/core@^4.9.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN restaurant_project@1.0.0 No description
npm WARN restaurant_project@1.0.0 No repository field.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.11 (node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.11: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

+ @material-ui/core@3.2.0
added 4 packages from 4 contributors, removed 26 packages, updated 5 packages and audited 11946 packages in 25.503s    
found 0 vulnerabilities
```

This looks worrisome, it seems like the lab is asking for core4.9.0, but okay:

`npm install --save-dev @material-ui/core@^4.0.0`

```
npm WARN @material-ui/lab@4.0.0-alpha.40 requires a peer of @material-ui/core@^4.9.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN material-ui-pickers@2.2.4 requires a peer of @material-ui/core@^3.2.0 but none is installed. You must install 
peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN restaurant_project@1.0.0 No description
npm WARN restaurant_project@1.0.0 No repository field.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.11 (node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.11: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

+ @material-ui/core@4.0.0
added 26 packages from 8 contributors, removed 6 packages, updated 1 package and audited 12027 packages in 14.485s     
found 0 vulnerabilities
```

So now it's telling me I need @material-ui/core@^3.2.0 again -- great, let me see if I can ignore that (it'll clear out the 4.9.0 I just installed)

`npm install --save-dev @material-ui/core@^4.9.0`

```
npm WARN material-ui-pickers@2.2.4 requires a peer of @material-ui/core@^3.2.0 but none is installed. You must install 
peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN restaurant_project@1.0.0 No description
npm WARN restaurant_project@1.0.0 No repository field.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.11 (node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.11: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

+ @material-ui/core@4.9.0
added 5 packages from 4 contributors, removed 3 packages, updated 5 packages and audited 12007 packages in 15.823s     
found 0 vulnerabilities
```

Alright, let's see if I can build it now.

No dice

```
ERROR in ./src/components/StepSlider/StepSlider-view.jsx
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@material-ui/lab/Slider' in 'D:\GIT\...\src\components\StepSlider'
 @ ./src/components/StepSlider/StepSlider-view.jsx 2:0-45 29:26-32
 @ ./src/components/StepSlider/index.js
 @ ./src/components/plan_option_slider/PlanOptionSlider-view.jsx
 @ ./src/components/plan_option_slider/index.jsx
 @ ./src/features/plans/plans-view.jsx
 @ ./src/features/plans/index.jsx
 @ ./src/App.jsx
 @ ./src/index.jsx
```

I'll try updating everything:

`npm update`

```
npm WARN deprecated popper.js@1.16.1: Popper changed home, find its new releases at @popperjs/core
npm WARN material-ui-pickers@2.2.4 requires a peer of @material-ui/core@^3.2.0 but none is installed. You must install 
peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN restaurant_project@1.0.0 No description
npm WARN restaurant_project@1.0.0 No repository field.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.11 (node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.11: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

+ popper.js@1.16.1
updated 1 package and audited 12007 packages in 14.471s
found 0 vulnerabilities
```

build again:

no dice

```
ERROR in ./src/components/StepSlider/StepSlider-view.jsx
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@material-ui/lab/Slider' in 'D:\GIT\...\src\components\StepSlider'
 @ ./src/components/StepSlider/StepSlider-view.jsx 2:0-45 29:26-32
 @ ./src/components/StepSlider/index.js
 @ ./src/components/plan_option_slider/PlanOptionSlider-view.jsx
 @ ./src/components/plan_option_slider/index.jsx
 @ ./src/features/plans/plans-view.jsx
 @ ./src/features/plans/index.jsx
 @ ./src/App.jsx
 @ ./src/index.jsx
```

I'll try w/ the new popper

`npm install @popperjs/core`

```
npm WARN material-ui-pickers@2.2.4 requires a peer of @material-ui/core@^3.2.0 but none is installed. You must install 
peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN restaurant_project@1.0.0 No description
npm WARN restaurant_project@1.0.0 No repository field.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.11 (node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.11: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

+ @popperjs/core@2.0.0
added 1 package from 1 contributor and audited 12008 packages in 19.887s
found 0 vulnerabilities
```

**I'm lost, any help would be REALLY appreciated**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://material-ui.com/guides/migration-v3/

```
[Container] Moved from @material-ui/lab to @material-ui/core.

-import Container from '@material-ui/lab/Container';
+import Container from '@material-ui/core/Container';
```

after reading this I tested to see if they moved `Slider` too, they did.

```
import Slider from '@material-ui/lab/Slider';
```

should be

```
import Slider from '@material-ui/core/Slider';
```

Hope this saves someone else the time I wasted