# buefy@0.9.3 requires a peer of vue@^2.6.11 but none is installed

Tags: vue.js, buefy

I want to install the latest version of buefy in my project, which is 0.9.3. Currently I have installed 0.8.3

If I run `npm install -g buefy@latest` I receive

> npm WARN buefy@0.9.3 requires a peer of vue@^2.6.11 but none is
> installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
>
> - buefy@0.9.3 updated 1 package in 0.511s

However, Buefey 0.8.2 remains installed in package.json

I also have difficulties to understand the error, because I have vue `2.6.12` installed.

I tried to run (as explained in https://stackoverflow.com/a/58254678/2311074)

```
$  npm install --save-dev "vue@^2.6.11"
```

which returned

```
adam@adam-MS-7A63:~/www/homestead/memberportal$ npm install --save-dev "vue@^2.6.11"
npm WARN laravel-mix-purgecss@5.0.0 requires a peer of laravel-mix@^5.0.1 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN trumbowyg@2.21.0 requires a peer of jQuery@>=1.8 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN vuetifyjs-mix-extension@0.0.2 requires a peer of laravel-mix@^5.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.13 (node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.13: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@2.1.3 (node_modules/watchpack/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.1.3: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})

+ vue@2.6.12
updated 1 package and audited 1679 packages in 4.824s

33 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 27 vulnerabilities (24 low, 3 high)
  run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details
```

but I still get the same message when trying to upgrade buefy.

Any hints what I am missing? Here is my  `package.json`:

```
{
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "npm run development",
        "development": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "watch": "npm run development -- --watch",
        "watch-poll": "npm run watch -- --watch-poll",
        "hot": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --inline --open --hot --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "prod": "npm run production",
        "production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --no-progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "axios": "^0.19",
        "babel-plugin-component": "^1.1.1",
        "bootstrap": "^4.5.2",
        "cross-env": "^7.0",
        "deepmerge": "^4.2.2",
        "fibers": "^4.0.2",
        "jquery": "^3.5.1",
        "laravel-mix": "^4.1.4",
        "laravel-mix-purgecss": "^5.0.0-rc.1",
        "lodash": "^4.17.20",
        "popper.js": "^1.12",
        "purify-css": "^1.2.5",
        "purifycss-webpack": "^0.7.0",
        "resolve-url-loader": "^2.3.1",
        "sass": "^1.27.0",
        "sass-loader": "^7.3.1",
        "vue": "^2.6.12",
        "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.12",
        "vuetifyjs-mix-extension": "0.0.2"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "axiom": "^0.1.6",
        "buefy": "^0.8.20",
        "element-ui": "^2.13.1",
        "modal-video": "^2.4.2",
        "prod": "^1.0.1",
        "trumbowyg": "^2.21.0",
        "vue-multiselect": "^2.1.6",
        "vue-scrollto": "^2.19.1",
        "vue-trumbowyg": "^3.6.2",
        "vuetify": "^2.3.13",
        "vuetify-loader": "^1.6.0"
    }
}
```

Comment: As a sidenote,why most of the packages you use are installed as `devDependencies`? I mean, yes, it's most likely won't matter much in your case (it doesn't seem to be a package by the logs) - unless one day you start running your `npm i` in production mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`npm install -g` means you're trying to install a package globally.