# Installation failure Capture-website-cli 3-0-1 and nodejs 14

Tags: node-js-14

Restart: in my Question I have shortend a long story.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76249271/puppeeer-old-headless-deprecation-warning-capture-website-cli-3-0-1

This may cause why it was ignored. So I deleted it. To begin with again. I am workung with capture-website-cli (cwc) since about three years and appreciate it, because I used it for bulk screenshots. My OS is windows 10.
After reinstallation of version 2.0.3 I realiced that cwc uses a new puppeteer whih caused the warning:

```
"Puppeteer old Headless deprection warning: ......."
```

I downloaded the latest cwc 3.0.1, removed the old version of node.js and installed node.js 14 as recommended by sindre sidorus. After installing and removing node 14.0.0x86.msi, 14.17.0x86.msi and 14.21.3x86.msi I always get the warning

```
"npm WARN type-fest@3.10.0 requires a peer of typescript@>=4.7.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself."
```

I read in stackoverflow

[npm WARN ... requires a peer of ... but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46053414/npm-warn-requires-a-peer-of-but-none-is-installed-you-must-install-peer)

to use the comandline

```
npm install -g npm-install-peers
```

but without any effect.

Nevertheless I installed cwc 3.0.1, but the warining

```
"Puppeeer old Headless deprecation warning: ……."
```

still appears. It works well, but what shall I do to avoid the warnings?