# How does package_json know if you're in development mode or in production mode?

Tags: javascript, npm, package.json

How does the package_json know when to load devDependencies vs normal dependencies? How can it tell when you're running locally vs. in production?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the difference between dependencies, devDependencies and peerDependencies in npm package.json file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18875674/whats-the-difference-between-dependencies-devdependencies-and-peerdependencies)

Answer (score 2):

by default you are in development mode when you run something like `npm install`. you need to add `--production` to switch.

So if you want to install only `dependencies` and don't install `devDependencies` you simply can use `npm install --production`

Comment: Say when you deploy to production, how does it know then to not run the devDependencies?

Comment: deploy - is not the base npm functionality. It is just convenience that we call our deploy process exactly deploy. And you should manually configure your webbuilder (webpack, gulp etc) to cut devDependencies. In many popular frameworks it is already configured and you don't need to worry about it