# Should I use devDependencies or dependencies in the package.json in a ASP.NET MVC project?

Tags: visual-studio, angular, npm, gulp

I'm creating a [ASP.NET Core 2.0 MVC application](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2017/08/14/announcing-asp-net-core-2-0/) and integrating with [Angular 4](https://angular.io/). I created a NPM package configuration file called `package.json` and saved in the root folder.

I don't want to use **angular-cli**, but use **Gulp** to compile and bundle the angular files.

I'm getting errors when the Visual Studio 2017 install the packages. Should I use `devDependencies` or `dependencies` in the `package.json` file.

`{
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "name": "asp.net",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/common": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/core": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/http": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/router": "^4.2.4",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "gulp-babel": "7.0.0",
    "gulp-concat": "2.6.1",
    "gulp-sourcemaps": "2.6.1",
    "gulp-typescript": "3.2.1",
    "minimatch": "3.0.4",
    "minimist": "1.2.0",
    "rimraf": "2.6.1",
    "require-dir": "0.3.2",
    "rxjs": "^5.4.2",
    "systemjs-builder": "0.16.9",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.14",
    "typescript": "2.4.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/common": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/core": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/http": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/router": "^4.2.4",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "gulp-babel": "7.0.0",
    "gulp-concat": "2.6.1",
    "gulp-sourcemaps": "2.6.1",
    "gulp-typescript": "3.2.1",
    "minimatch": "3.0.4",
    "minimist": "1.2.0",
    "rimraf": "2.6.1",
    "require-dir": "0.3.2",
    "rxjs": "^5.4.2",
    "systemjs-builder": "0.16.9",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.14",
    "typescript": "2.4.2"
  }
}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the short answer is you should use both, dependencies for UI libraries that you want to bundle, and devDependencies for those that allow you to develop the app.

there's an awesome explanation in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22004559/1303897