# Unable to resolve sequelize package

Tags: node.js, macos, npm, sequelize.js, npm-install

I'm trying to install sequelize-cli in my Mac OS 10.12.6.

In Terminal, I did

`npm install -g sequelize-cli`

I got

```
npm WARN deprecated minimatch@2.0.10: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
npm WARN deprecated minimatch@0.2.14: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
npm WARN deprecated graceful-fs@1.2.3: graceful-fs v3.0.0 and before will fail on node releases >= v7.0. Please update to graceful-fs@^4.0.0 as soon as possible. Use 'npm ls graceful-fs' to find it in the tree.
/usr/local/bin/sequelize -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/sequelize-cli/bin/sequelize
/usr/local/lib
└── sequelize-cli@2.8.0
```

Then, I tried

`sequelize model:create --name User --attributes name:string,complete:boolean`

I got

> Unable to resolve sequelize package in /Users/bheng/Sites/BASE

I even try with the `--save` as this [post](https://github.com/sequelize/cli/issues/119) suggested.

`npm install -g sequelize-cli --save`

I got same result.

```
npm WARN deprecated minimatch@2.0.10: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
npm WARN deprecated minimatch@0.2.14: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
npm WARN deprecated graceful-fs@1.2.3: graceful-fs v3.0.0 and before will fail on node releases >= v7.0. Please update to graceful-fs@^4.0.0 as soon as possible. Use 'npm ls graceful-fs' to find it in the tree.
/usr/local/bin/sequelize -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/sequelize-cli/bin/sequelize
/usr/local/lib
└── sequelize-cli@2.8.0
```

`sequelize model:create --name User --attributes name:string,complete:boolean`

> Unable to resolve sequelize package in /Users/bheng/Sites/BASE

What else should I try ?

Comment: If someone faces the same issue make sure you install sequelize first

Answer (score 55, accepted):

In sequelize-cli [package.json](https://github.com/sequelize/cli/blob/master/package.json) file, sequelize is mentioned as a devdependency which means it does not install it when you do `npm install sequelize-cli`. My guess is you have not installed sequelize itself and this is what the error says.

> Unable to resolve sequelize package in /Users/bheng/Sites/BASE

install sequelize `npm install --save sequelize`  (or global) and things should be good.

PS: [Great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18875674/whats-the-difference-between-dependencies-devdependencies-and-peerdependencies) on different dependencies and what they mean

Answer (score 12):

I had the same issue. I installed `sequelize-cli` forgetting to add  `sequelize` itself:

`npm install sequelize`

Answer (score 5):

you can try this one

`npm install --save-dev sequelize sequelize-cli`

`npx sequelize-cli init`

Once you get `models` `migrations` folders, means `sequelize` is working.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to install sequelize globally.

> npm install -g sequelize

Answer (score 1):

First you have need to install sequelize package, after then execute cli command.

Comment: how is your answer different than the accepted one?

Comment: Because it is simple as it is.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. This is "normal" the CLI will try to find the sequelize package in your current working directory and/or in the node paths. So you could either install the package in your local dir or in any parent directory or in the global space.

[more answers](https://github.com/sequelize/cli/issues/119)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar case where when I was trying to run any sequelize command.

ie. `sequelize init` or `sequelize --help`

I would get the error:

`Unable to resolve sequelize package in <my-project-directory>`

None of the solutions above where helping my case but after farther digging I found this [article](https://teamtreehouse.com/community/is-the-order-of-dependencies-important) talking about the importance of the order in which one installs dependencies.

I had installed my my development dependencies first (sequelize-cli before sequelize) and that's why it wasn't working.

Because this is a new project I just removed my yarn files and the package.json (left my other files untouched) and started over and this time I did:

1. `yarn init`
2. `yarn add <my dependencies>`
3. `yarn add --dev <my development dependencies>`

This solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

when downloading sequelize and sequlize-cli , you have to install both globally using -g option

> npm install -g sequelize

> npm install -g sequelize-cli

that's all