# How do dev dependences in npm work?

Tags: npm, babeljs

I'm confused on why the packages in the `dev` environment aren't needed in the production environment. For example the `babel-plugin-lodash` lets you do some transformations for free, but won't you still need them when your code is running in production?

```
$ npm i --save lodash
$ npm i --save-dev babel-plugin-lodash babel-cli babel-preset-es2015
```

Comment: Babel doesn't run client-side. It's used in the dev environment to *build* browser-friendly JavaScript for production out of your ES6/ES7/ES∞ code, so dev is appropriate.

Comment: This might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18875674/whats-the-difference-between-dependencies-devdependencies-and-peerdependencies

Comment: @ceejayoz so that means that the still in `--save-dev` is during the build process, regardless of the final bundle being used for development or production? And then the packages in `--save` will always be served as part of that bundle? I've always thought the dev environment refers to when you're developing code locally, not to a stage at which the code is being built to be served.

Comment: Building *for* production is a development process.

Comment: @ceejayoz how does it work if you `yarn add` a package and your project doesn't install that package's devDependencies? Doesn't that mean that the package won't be able to be built to be used by your project?

Comment: `devDependencies` are what you need to develop that module. You don't need them to simply *use* that module.

Comment: @ceejayoz say a package has a devDependency on babel and webpack to be built, how can you not need to them in order to use that package if that package needs them to be built? does it not have to be built in order to be used?

Comment: @ceejayoz If devDependencies aren't in the picture at all, how does a package that relies on webpack and babel to transcompile its es6 into es5 work within a project that requires the package but that project is only in es5?