# Warning about npm as peer dependency

Tags: npm, npm-install

`npm install` outputs the following warning:

```
npm WARN nswag@11.11.3 requires a peer of npm@>=3.10.8 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
```

`npm -v` outputs `5.5.1`

Why is npm complaining about the missing peer dependency?

This question isn't a duplicate of [What's the difference between dependencies, devDependencies and peerDependencies in npm package.json file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18875674/whats-the-difference-between-dependencies-devdependencies-and-peerdependencies). That question doesn't even mention `engines` and doesn't explain that `peerDependencies` are not searched among global packages.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the difference between dependencies, devDependencies and peerDependencies in npm package.json file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18875674/whats-the-difference-between-dependencies-devdependencies-and-peerdependencies)

Answer (score 0):

Peer dependencies are not searched among global packages (https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/9857). `npm` should be installed locally for the peer dependency to be satisfied.

In this case, if the `nswag` package does not need the `npm` package installed locally, it should list it in `engines` instead of in `peerDependencies`.