# Axios, dependencies or devdependencies?

Tags: webpack, vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js

I've a question though a silly one but I really need to know. If we're using axios then should I install it as dependencies or devdependencies? As I understand that webpack will bundle it in vendor file then installing it in production server as dependencies is just pointless. 
Please advise

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the difference between dependencies, devDependencies and peerDependencies in npm package.json file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18875674/whats-the-difference-between-dependencies-devdependencies-and-peerdependencies)

Comment: Not a duplicate, but the answers there are implicitly the answers to this question.

Answer (score 14):

You should install it as a `dependencies` because you use it in your application, not only as a `dev tool`.

Comment: However when bootstraping a Laravel app, the package.json puts it in devDependencies

Comment: This answer is incorrect or not best practice.

Answer (score 2):

`devDependencies`. Put everything that is not included in the consuming application e.g. through a compilation step into dev dependencies. This way the consumers of your package or your production install or your docker container will  not include an unused dependency. Your users will thank you.