# Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@angular/material' when building dist for npm package

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material

I'm building an npm package that depends on `@angular/material`.

I've included in my `package.json` (hiding irrelevant info)

```
{
  "main": "dist/index.js",
  "module": "dist/index.js",
  "types": "./dist/index.d.ts",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "build": "ngc"
  },
  "peerDependencies": {
    "@angular/core": ">=4.0.0 <5.0.0 || >=4.0.0-beta <5.0.0",
    "@angular/animations": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^5.0.4",
    "@angular/material": "^5.0.4",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.4.6",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.4.6",
    "@angular/core": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/animations": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^5.0.4",
    "@angular/material": "^5.0.4",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "rollup": "^0.50.0",
    "rxjs": "^5.4.1",
    "typescript": "^2.6.1",
    "uglify-js": "^3.1.6",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.4"
  }
}
```

I build the package with `./node_modules/.bin/ngc` without any problem. But when I use this package in my local project, I'm getting the following error:

```
ERROR in /Users/me/myPackage/dist/myPackage.module.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@angular/material/slider/' in '/Users/me/myPackage/dist'
 @ /Users/me/myPackage/dist/morpheus.module.js 49:0-60
 @ /Users/me/myPackage/dist/index.js
 @ ./src/app/app.module.ts
 @ ./src/main.ts
 @ multi webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:4200 ./src/main.ts
webpack: Failed to compile.
```

Comment: Have you tried deleting the `node_modules` folder and running `npm install` again?

Comment: Yes.. No luck unfortunately..

Answer (score 0):

You need to move some dependencies from `devDependencies` to either `dependencies` or `peerDependencies` (according to your requirements). This regards dependencies, that need to be available in the project that uses your package. Also, you should not have them in both groups, as e. g. `"@angular/material": "^5.0.4"`.

Most of your dependencies should probably be `peerDependencies`, such that those dependencies won't be installed multiple times in different versions in the project that uses your package.

For further information about the differences, have a look at this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22004559/4694994).