# Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'ngDevMode' with angular 6 when installing ng-bootstrap-modal

Tags: angular, typescript, ng-bootstrap

Today I've installed `ng-bootstrap-modal` into my angular `6.0.8` project. After `ng serve`ing the following compile errors are displayed:

> ERROR in node_modules/@angular/core/src/render3/ng_dev_mode.d.ts(9,11): error
>   TS2451: Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'ngDevMode'.
>   node_modules/ng-bootstrap-modal/node_modules/@angular/core/src/render3/ng_dev_mode.d.ts(9,11):
>   error TS2451: Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'ngDevMode'.

When I looked into the package dependencies I can see it's requiring angular 5.x.x (`^5.0.0`) and because of this (I think so) the installation created a folder `node_modules\ng-bootstrap-modal\node_modules` with another `@angular` as one of its subfolders which is causing the error I guess.

I read some threads on github and here about this that suggest (mostly) adding a `"paths"` property to the `TS` compiler options at `tsconfig.json` but I couldn't get it done, they are:

- [error TS2451: Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'ngDevMode'](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/21670)
- [Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'ngDevMode'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48926322/cannot-redeclare-block-scoped-variable-ngdevmode)
- [Error upgrading to Angular 6: Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'ngDevMode'](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/24165)

Some of my attempts were:

- `"paths": { "ng-bootstrap-modal/*": ["../ng-bootstrap-modal/src/*"] }`
- `"paths": { "ng-bootstrap-modal/*": ["ng-bootstrap-modal/src/*"] }`
- `"paths": { "@angular/*": ["node_modules/@angular/*"] } }`

What I'd like to know is if there's some workaround (that doesn't involve downgrading my project to `^5.0.0`) to make `ng-bootstrap-modal` to work or if this isn't possible at all so I start looking for other modals packages.

Any help is more than appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Well... what I posted may or may not be possible but either way I found a very easy-to-use package for displaying modals: [ngx-smart-modal](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-smart-modal)