# What if I installed devDependency package as dependency, do I need to reinstall it as devDependency?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Most of the time, when I need to install a package as a `devDependency` but I forget to add `--save-dev` command thus this installation is final to `dependency`.

#### What I do:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@types/express": "^4.11.1"
},
"devDependencies": {

}
```

#### But my requirement is:

```
"dependencies": {

},
"devDependencies": {
    "@types/express": "^4.11.1"    
}
```

Now, do I need to reinstall it as `devDependency` or `cut` and `paste` in `devDependency` is OK?

Comment: Check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18875674/whats-the-difference-between-dependencies-devdependencies-and-peerdependencies)

Comment: I know the difference but question is do I need to reinstall the package for `devDependency` or just `copying` and `pasting` in `devDependency` array is ok

Comment: some days ago I went through this link you provided.

Comment: You can copy/past the package from devDependencies to dependencies.