# Ember: fa-icon is not a helper

Tags: ember.js, font-awesome-5

I recently installed the [Ember Font Awesome plugin](https://github.com/FortAwesome/ember-fontawesome) into [ember-social-share](https://github.com/Crabar/ember-social-share) to make it easy to render icons. It worked for me locally, however now when I add ember-social-share to my application and call it, I get...:

> Uncaught Error: Compile Error: fa-icon is not a helper

I've seen a lot of documentation online about how this is an issue people have run into, but I haven't been able to find a solution. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at your fork of `ember-social-share` you do not list `ember-font-awesome` as a dependency.

On a side note I would recommend importing and extending the components in your consuming app rather than maintaining your own fork as this will be harder to maintain as updates roll in.

Comment: It is listed, but it's called [@fortawesome/ember-fontawesome](https://github.com/FortAwesome/ember-fontawesome), which is the official plugin for font awesome. Unless I'm misunderstanding and it needs to go somewhere else as well?

Comment: You're listing it under `devDependencies` you need it to be under `dependencies` @BDD

Comment: Oooooh, I see. I wasn't really sure of the difference until I saw this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18875674/whats-the-difference-between-dependencies-devdependencies-and-peerdependencies?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa. Thank you!!

Comment: @BDD when dealing with addons if you expose a 3rd party resource from within your addon it has to make it into `dependencies`, in your main consuming app everything goes under `devDependencies` since you do not publish the package itself but you use packages at build time.